# JavaScript Object literal notation confusion

Tags: javascript, json

In Firefox console, this code will generate error:

```
{"d" : ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"] } 
>   SyntaxError: invalid label {
> message="invalid label",  more...}
```

this code works just fine

```
{d : ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"] } 
> ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"]
```

this code works fine as well

```
var a = {'d' : ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"] };
a.d
> ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"]
```

Can someone help to explain why is the diference? thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509535/javascript-false-and-false/1509664#1509664 is a seemingly irrelevant question, but with a relevant answer to one thing you may be tripping on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of ambiguous syntax. When you try to make a plain object literal in the first two lines, JavaScript is really interpreting it as a set of braces, then a label, then a statement:

```
{
    d: ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"]
}
```

This code doesn't evaluate to an object, but just to the array. The first example, you tried to use a string as a label, which is incorrect syntax. The third example works properly, creating an object and storing it in `a`.

Comment: +1 @OP: In order for it to be an expression (an object literal) rather than braces around a label followed by an array literal, you have to use it as a right-hand value (as in your last example). As right-hand values, all three of those would have been valid object literal notation (the one using `d:`, the one using `"d":`, and the one using `'d':`). Somewhat OT, but only the `"d":` one would be valid JSON, if that's relevant to what you're doing, because JSON is a *subset* of object literal notation. (http://json.org)

Comment: Why, oh why, did they put GOTOs in Javascript... *sigh*

Comment: @Bears: They didn't, Javascript doesn't have `goto` statements. It does have labels, which are useful for `break`ing out of inner loops and such. (See section 12.12 of the 5th edition specification. In earlier specs, `goto` was a reserved symbol but there was no `goto` statement -- e.g., they were hedging their bets. As of 5th edition, no more hedging.)

Comment: @Oscar: The 2nd example doesn't work. It doesn't produce an object literal. It just happens to be valid syntax for evaluating a block with a label and an array expression

Answer (score 4):

it is probably having a hard time deciding whether it is an expression or a block. If you use parenthesis around the object it works as it forces an expression. The grouping operator, `(` and `)`, forces `{` and `}` to be parsed as object literal.

```
({"d" : ["bankaccountnumber", "$1234.56"] }) // works
```

Read [Named function expressions demystified](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/). Its not directly related to this issue but does address it when talking about the use of grouping-parenthesis and `eval()`.