# Why does {a:1} evaluate to 1 in the console

Tags: javascript, console, syntax-error

I why does the console in Chrome and Firefox evaluate the current to `1`:

```
> {a:1}
1
```

I would guess that it would be evaluated as an object like if you assign it to a variable:

```
> var a = {a:1}
undefined
> a
Object {a: 1}
```

And with quotes it throws an syntax error:

```
> {"a":1}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: I noticed the same `SyntaxError` when I did `{a:1,b:2}`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3731802/5445

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `({a:1})`.

Just executing `{a:1}` is not what you think it is.  It is not an object literal, which must be an expression (for example, on the right side of assignment).

Instead, what you have is a [block](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1), a [label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12), and then a 1.

```
{
    a:
    1
}
```

Blocks return the result of their evaluation, and labels return the result of evaluating the statement that follows the label, so `1` is returned.

Comment: What would a label be doing there? How would it be use full or would it not?

Comment: @NULL [MDN label docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: @NULL, per spec, labels can only be used with the `break` and `continue` statements.  However, even though you have no way of using the label in this particular context, there's nothing *syntactically* invalid about defining one.  It's a peculiarity.