# How can {} + [] and [] + {} results be different

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Could someone explain to me how thees returning results can be different in javascript:

```
› {} + []
» 0
› [] + {}
» "[object Object]"
```

Comment: Because it's Javascript... who says it has to make sense?!!

Comment: [`WAT`](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Comment: @Mehrdad it's all in the specs http://stackoverflow.com/a/9033306/135448, now depending on what you mean by "making sense" ;)

Comment: I think I read this exact same question yesterday...

Comment: yep, attempting to close/merge..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `{}` in the code is **not** an object literal, but an empty block.

It is parsed as:

```
{};   // empty block
+ []; // this result is shown in the console
```

Compare with `({}) + []` which yields the same results as `[] + {}`; in this case the parenthesis force the `{}` to be treated/parsed "in an expression context".

There are a *bunch* of duplicates on SO about this particular dual-nature of `{}` (as an expression or block?) but, finding them can be somewhat tricky ..

---

I found https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83911/how-do-i-search-stackoverflow-for-at-keywords-like-private-or-synthesize on Meta, and using Symbolhound the "closest" duplicates I could find resolved around questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731802/what-is-the-behavior-of-typing-a1-giving-1-and-a1-b2-giving-an-error-in?lq=1) (that relate to the need to add parenthesis when "eval'ing JSON") or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509535/javascript-false-is-a-syntaxerror?lq=1) (where the use of constructs like "{} == false" is a syntax error).

If anyone knows a better way to search SO for this sort question, or has a link to such a duplicate handy ..

Comment: @ErikLandvall If you find some duplicates, just vote to close/link :) Don't delete the question, it will be closed as/if appropriate.

Comment: Actually finding the duplicates is the problem. I'm sure I saw the same question within the last couple of days, but searching on `[]` doesn't work too well.

Comment: Yea, I had that problem to. Now I'm just trying to merge them as pst stated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the