# Referencing a JavaScript value before it is declared - can someone explain this

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping someone can explain to me why the below JavaScript/HTML will show "door #2" when the HTML is viewed in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testprint() {
            alert('door #1');
        };

        window.onload = testprint;

        function testprint() {
            alert('door #2');
        };

        testprint = function() {
            alert('door #3');
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testprint() {
            alert('door #4');
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Since only the declaration `testprint` occurs before `window.onload` is set to `testprint`, I would expect `window.onload` cause 'door #1' to show up.  Actually, onload causes 'door #2'.  Note that it will do this whether the first declaration of `testprint` is included or not.

The third and fourth declaration of `testprint` use different means of assigning the function, I tried this to see if it would override `window.onload`'s behavior in the same was the second declaration of `testprint` does.  It did not.  Note that if I move the fourth declaration of `testprint` to the end of the first script block it would be called by `window.onload`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Function declarations are subject of hoisting, and they are evaluated at parse time, by hoisting means that they are available to the entire scope in where they were declared, for example:

```
foo(); // alerts foo
foo = function () { alert('bar')};
function foo () { alert('foo');}
foo(); // alerts bar
```

The first call to `foo` will execute the **function declaration**, because at *parse time* it was made available, the second call of `foo` will execute the **function expression**, declared at *run-time*.

For a more detailed discussion about the differences between function expressions and function declarations, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax) and [this article](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/).

Comment: There is one subtlety to function hoisting where [browsers disagree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Conditionally_defining_a_function). _SpiderMonkey_ **will not** hoist functions declared in a conditional scope while _V8_ (at the time of writing) does so.

Answer (score 0):

The reason #3 doesn't change window.onload is that functions are called by reference, not by name. When you set `window.onload = testprint`, it assigns reference to the current value of `testprint` (door #2, as explained by CMS) to `window.onload`. Changing `testprint`'s value later doesn't affect `window.onload`'s value.

Door #4 doesn't override door #2 (unless, as you said, you move it to the first script block) because it's in a different script block, so it gets parsed after the first block is completed.

Answer (score -1):

function testprint is global to the page.
the testprint = function... assigns a variable, that I'm not sure exactly the entire scope of, but I get the idea that it's not added to the function table dictionary the way the first one is.