# Javascript difference between functions within an object

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between functions within an object. I have 2 examples which basically do the same thing.

```
function a(param) {
   function b(input) {
      return input%10;
   };
return 'The result is ' + b(param);
};
```

and

```
function a(param) {
   this.b=function(input) {
      return input%10;
   };
return 'The result is ' + this.b(param);
};
```

What is the advantage and the disadvatages in both cases? In the second i know that that function can be called from outside the main function.
Is there also a difference when running it? (like time and performance)

Answer (score 11):

You have to be careful with the second example, the `this` keyword will refer to the Global object if you invoke the function without the `new` operator, and by looking at your return value, seems that you aren't trying to make a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function).

I think you need to know how the `this` keyword (the function context) works:

The `this` keyword is **implicitly** set when:

1- When a function is called as a method (the function is invoked as member of an object):

```
obj.method(); // 'this' inside method will refer to obj
```

2- A normal function call:

```
myFunction(); // 'this' inside the function will refer to the Global object
// or 
(function () {})();
```

3- When the `new` operator is used:

```
var obj = new MyObj(); // this will refer to a newly created object.
```

And you can also set the `this` keyword **explicitly**, with the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) methods:

```
function test () {
  alert(this);
}

test.call("Hello world"); // alerts 'Hello world'
```

Now, the difference between the `b` function of your two examples, is basically that in the first snippet, `b` is a *function declaration*, in your second example `b` is a *function expression*.

Function declaration are subject to [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710424/referencing-a-javascript-value-before-it-is-declared-can-someone-explain-this/1710509#1710509), and they are evaluated at parse time, on function expressions are defined at run-time.

If you want more details of the differences between function declarations and function expressions, I leave you some resources:

- [Explain JavaScript's Encapsulated Anonymous Function Ssyntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321)
- [Named function expressions demystified](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/)

And BTW, you don't need the [semicolon after function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript/1834674#1834674).