# object name same a function name?

Tags: javascript

If We have

```
var randomname = {};
randomname.attribute = 'something';

function randomname(){
  alert(randomname.attribute);
}
randomname();
```

Will javascript throw any errors?

---

**Update**
So, We know that we cannot have a object have the same name as a function.

Why is this?

Should javascript not be able to tell what you are after by the way you call it?

Comment: this actually surprised me and thats great to know about. but if you want to use the same name perhaps you should use var name = function(){} instead to avoid consciously thinking about this subtle behavior anymore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should give you a `TypeError` exception -for trying to invoke an object-, the behavior observed in the Firebug's console is not right...

`FunctionDeclaration`'s are [*hoisted*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710424/referencing-a-javascript-value-before-it-is-declared-can-someone-explain-this/1710509#1710509) to the top of their enclosing scope, your code is actually executing in this order:

```
// FunctionDeclaration is hoisted
function randomname(){
  alert(randomname.attribute);
}

// the var has no observable effect, because
// the randonmane identifier is already defined
randomname = {};
randomname.attribute = 'something';

randomname(); // TypeError, randomname is not callable.
```

When entering to an execution context, the [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) process (aka [Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.5) in ES5) defines the properties on the [Activation Object](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.6) (AO, *this is a non-reachable object that holds identifiers of variables, functions declarations and function arguments in the local scope*) in the following order:

1. `FormalParameterList` identifiers (for [Function Code](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.2.3))
2. `FunctionDeclaration` identifiers
3. `VariableDeclaration` identifiers

A `VariableDeclaration` will not overwrite an identifier has been already defined in the AO (e.g. by one of the first two steps), but the assignment will do it at run time.

For example:

```
(function (foo) {
  var foo; // doesn't affect the existing `foo` identifier
  return typeof foo;
  function foo () {}
})('string'); // yields "function"
```

But if an assignment is made, the value of the identifier will be replaced, for example:

```
(function (foo) {
  var foo = {};
  return typeof foo;
  function foo () {}
})('string'); // yields "object"!!
```

In the above example, when the function is invoked, -but before the code execution- the `foo` identifier is set up on the Activation Object (aka Variable Object).

First it gets assigned the value of the formal parameter, the value `'string'`, then all `FunctionDeclaration`'s on the Function Body are examined, a function named `foo` is found, then the `foo` identifier will point to that function.

After that, all Variable Declarations are examined, we have one with the identifier `foo`, but its value is respected in this time -remember that the function hasn't been executed-.

At this point, the function is ready to be executed, its lexical and variable environment is setup.

The first thing that will be executed in the function, is the assignment `foo = {};`, which replaces the reference to the function that we had before.

**Why it behaves differently on other browsers and Firefox?**

Because:

1. The Firebug's console [wraps your code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#BmTejM3fPxA/content/firebug/commandLine.js&l=80) before evaluating it.
2. The Mozilla implementations define a [Function Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

Since Firebug evaluates code by wrapping inside a `with` statement, this causes the `FunctionDeclaration` to be evaluated in *statement context* -a Mozilla's Function Statement-.

To show the behavior of the Function statement on Mozilla implementations, consider the following example:

```
if (true) {
  function foo () { return 'true!';}
} else {
  function foo () { return 'false??!';}
}

foo();
```

In Mozilla you will get `'true!'`, while in other implementations you will get `'false??!'` - even on IE-.

That's because the function definition was made at run-time, in Statement context (in side the true branch of the `if`), while in other implementations, the function declarations are evaluated at *parse time*.

The above example should actually produce a `SyntaxError` exception on any implementation, but that doesn't happen on any of them...

A `FunctionDeclaration` should be allowed only, in global code or directly in the FunctionBody of a function.

A [lot of](http://books.google.com/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&pg=PT119&dq="function+statement") [people](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html) use interchangeably the terms Function Declaration and Function Statement but that's totally wrong, ECMAScript doesn't define a Function Statement, is a [non-standard feature](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#functionStatement).

The specification has a brief [note](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12) on this issue:

> NOTE: Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to support the use of FunctionDeclaration as a Statement. However there are significant and irreconcilable variations among the implementations in the semantics applied to such FunctionDeclarations. Because of these irreconcilable difference, the use of a FunctionDeclaration as a Statement results in code that is not reliably portable among implementations. It is recommended that ECMAScript implementations either disallow this usage of FunctionDeclaration or issue a warning when such a usage is encountered. Future editions of ECMAScript may define alternative portable means for declaring functions in a Statement context.

Try to run your code in the global execution context -in a simple `<script>` element- and you will see it crash also on Firefox:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var randomname = {};
  randomname.attribute = 'something';

  function randomname(){
    alert(randomname.attribute);
  }
  randomname();
</script>
```

You can find the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/ajoko4/2), make sure to open the Firebug's console and you'll see the same error you get on other browsers.

Comment: All hail arcane implementation details. And I thought I knew stuff about Javascript. Though once again I think the official spec gets it wrong and do not intend to stop using Function Statements within other functions so long as it does not seem to cause issues (and so far I have not seen any).

Answer (score 5):

**function** also is actually an object(**first class object**) in JavaScript.

So you can do something like this.

```
var human = function(){
  alert("Hi");
};

// which is perfectly normal 

//but then

human.name="Anubhav";
```

And then you can do following:

```
human();//works
alert(human.name);//works
```

Comment: so how to print both the function `human` and object `human` , or are they just one object? in that case how to see its content?

Answer (score 3):

Your `function randomname()` is redefining the `randomname` identifier, thus losing your reference to the object you constructed earlier. It may look more clear like this:

```
var randomname = {};
randomname.attribute = 'something';

var randomname = function () {
  alert(randomname.attribute);
};

randomname();
```

It is like doing:

```
var a = 5;
var a = [20, 30];

console.log(a);  // returns [20, 30]
```

Comment: When using `function randomname () {}` as opposed to `var randomname = function () {}` there is different behavior. The former throws a TypeError, whereas the latter works correctly -- alerting with undefined. I do not think they are equivalent. Tried it in the WebKit console. EDIT: No errors are thrown in FF. Must be a WebKit console bug.

Comment: @Daniel: Checking in Chrome console, you're right. The example of the OP returns `Type Error`. Does not happen in Firebug. Looks like a WebKit bug to me too.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: I know the difference, but Chrome is throwing an error when not using variable assignment for the function definition. This is what I'm trying: http://pastebin.com/KzXQjLny

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, sorry. Deleted my comment after I found out that it's true :) I was only checking the second example (the one in my answer).

Comment: I tried it on http://jsfiddle.net/5vHtg/ and I still get the error, so it's not limited to the console. Odd.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, very strange! ... There's definitely something different happening in Chrome and Safari when using a function statement.

Comment: Anyone going to submit this as a bug to webkit?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if it is intentional... AFAIK Safari and Chrome use different JavaScript engines, and both are handling it in the same way.

Comment: If you have node.js (which uses v8, or chrome's JS engine) you could try running the code there. If it doesn't produce an error, then it's most likely related to WebKit.

Comment: Webkit is showing the "right" behavior, the function declaration makes the `randomname` identifier available when entering the execution context, later the assignment `randomname = {};` is made, Firebug is the one who has problems.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663775/object-name-same-a-function-name/3664199#3664199), I explain why Firefox behaves differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
function randomname(){
  alert(randomname.attribute);
}
```

is roughly the same as this:

```
var randomname = function() {
  alert(randomname.attribute);
}
```

It's not 100% identical, since with the first syntax you can refer to functions "in the future", but this is basically how it works. There is only once namespace for functions and variables, since functions get assigned to variables.

Comment: +1... I think the "functions in the future" thing is called *hoisting* :)

Comment: thanks about the "hoisting" and "future function" I did not about this until now

Comment: Oddly, in Chrome the two do not seem to be equivalent. The first example will throw a `TypeError`. I believe what you posted is the correct behavior, but just a heads up so someone doesn't get bitten by this "bug."

Answer (score 0):

forgive my pedant reply. your question is a bit confusing, or is this a tricky question. In the second line you wrote

```
var randomname.attribute....
```

if thats your point, then it is an illegal statement and will definitely throw an exception.
But if your point is about the fourth line where you reused the same name.

note that you wrote

```
function randomname(){...}
```

instead of

```
var randomname  = function(){...}
```

I dont know why, but because you used a future function, you wont be able to override preexisting names. therefore randomname will still be a hash instead of a function, thus throwing an exception.

My question is, so what will happen to randomname function? How can we call it? Is it a wasted resource? As a general rule I always use

```
var randomname = function{..}
```

template so I am always assured that name conflicts wont happen so I never encounter this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found an example of how it works.

In fact, I believe sequelize.js does it with the following code:

```
var STRING = function(length, binary) {
  if (this instanceof STRING) {
    this._binary = !!binary
    if (typeof length === 'number') {
      this._length = length
    } else {
      this._length = 255
    }
  } else {
    return new STRING(length, binary)
  }
}

STRING.prototype = {
  get BINARY() {
    this._binary = true
    return this
  },
  get type() {
    return this.toString()
  },
  toString: function() {
    return 'VARCHAR(' + this._length + ')' + ((this._binary) ? ' BINARY' : '')
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(STRING, 'BINARY', {
  get: function() {
    return new STRING(undefined, true)
  }
})
```

You can see it in their docs for data types: http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/models#block-2-line-0. Notice `Sequelize.STRING` and `Sequelize.STRING(1234)`