# Are there still ECMAScript 3 implementation differences in major browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Can someone point out the differences in implementation of ECMAScript 3rd edition in today's browsers? (Chrome, Safari, IE8, FF)

Are we safe when using ECMAScript 3 standards (and not the extensions that FF and IE have to JScript and JavaScript)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, of course there are implementation bugs, the most serious that I've had to deal with are on JScript, the Microsoft implementation of the standard, for example:

Identifier of FunctionExpressions should be accessible only in the inner scope of the function itself:

```
(function foo() {
  alert(typeof foo); // "function"
})();

alert(typeof foo);  // should be "undefined", on IE shows "function"
```

The bug is present on all current IE versions, it has just been fixed on IE9 Previews.

And actually is even worse, it creates two function objects, for example:

```
var foo = function bar() {};

if (typeof bar != 'undefined') { // the case of IE
  alert(foo === bar); // false!!!
}
```

Another well known JScript bug is the ["DontEnum Bug"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute), if an object in its scope chain contains a property that is not enumerable (has the `{ DontEnum }` attribute), if the property is shadowed on other object, it will stay as non-enumerable, for example:

```
var dontEnumBug = {toString:'foo'}.propertyIsEnumerable('toString');
```

It will evaluate to `false` on IE, this causes problems when using the `for-in` statement, because the properties will not be visited.

JScript is the implementation that has the largest number of problems -although the IE9 implementation is getting really way better-.

Recommended article:

- [JScript deviations from ES3](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=resources%3Aresources&cache=cache&media=resources:jscriptdeviationsfromes3.pdf)<sub>pdf</sub>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663775/object-name-same-a-function-name/ Your answer to that question would make a nice addition to this. The FunctionStatement part at least.

Comment: Nice examples. If you (or someone else) has more articles highlighting ecmascript 3 implementation differences in browsers send them :)

Comment: The link is down.

Comment: @corvus_192, found a copy of the document at: https://regmedia.co.uk/2007/10/31/jscriptdeviationsfromes3.pdf