# javascript testing for object property

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
var TheDate = "6.14.2012";
```

and I have an object `MyObject` that has properties that may match that string. However, when I write this:

```
if (MyObject[TheDate] === null || MyObject[TheDate] === 'undefined') { .... }
```

the conditions never seem to evaluate to true even though I know the property doesn't exist.

What am I missing??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the quotes around undefined ;)

Change

`if (MyObject[TheDate] === null || MyObject[TheDate] === 'undefined') { .... }`

to

`if (MyObject[TheDate] === null || MyObject[TheDate] === undefined) { .... }`

It should work :)

Comment: It is the one of the trusted way to do, provided you are operating with the property of an object :) else typeof x == "undefined" is good :)

Answer (score 3):

***Existence of Own Property***

If you want to check for the existence of a property use `.hasownProperty()`...

```
if (MyObject.hasOwnProperty(TheDate)) {
```

---

***Existence of Own Or Inherited Property***

If the property may be inherited, to test for existence use the `in` operator...

```
if (TheDate in MyObject) {
```

---

***`null` or `undefined` value test for Own Or Inherited Property***

If it's not existence, but rather a value test, and  you want to test for `null` or `undefined`, then use this...

```
if (MyObject[TheDate] == null) {
```

This will check for both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: hasOwnProperty doesn't seem to work well in IE8; not personally tested but seems well documented. I've avoided using it so far. How can this work safely in IE8?

Comment: @frenchie: That seems to be an edge case. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705383/ie8-bug-in-for-in-javascript-statement). But if you actually want to test for `null` or `undefined`, see the 3rd solution. If inherited property check is alright *(I'm guessing it probably is)*, see the 2nd solution using the `in` operator.

Comment: Ok, I decided to not use the hasOwnProperty method and simply remove the quotes and it works. Is .hasOwnProperty going to work better than if (MyObject[TheDate] === null || MyObject[TheDate] === undefined) ?

Comment: @frenchie: It all depends on what you're actually wanting to test. If you want to test to see if the property exists, you must use one of the first two solutions I gave. If you want to test for `null` or `undefined` values, then use the `MyObject[TheDate] == null`. There's no reason to test for them separately. This tests for both at the same time, because of the way the `==` operator works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the string `"undefined"` rather than the `undefined` object, the way to do this is to check the "typeof", which returns a string. In this case, if you're looking to test if it's set to "undefined":

```
if ( MyObject[TheDate] === null || typeof MyObject[TheDate] === 'undefined' ) { .... }
```

Comment: Sorry, you caught me mid-edit. The correct syntax is the above, which checks the object. Checking typeof of a string will always return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
if ( (MyObject[TheDate] === null) || (typeof MyObject[TheDate] === 'undefined') { 
 .... 
}
```

You were checking whether your property contains the String `'undefined'` and not whether its value is currently `undefined`.

Comment: typeof always returns a string. so (typeof MyObject[TheDate] === 'undefined') can be written as (typeof MyObject[TheDate] == 'undefined') with no worries.

Comment: @Angel `typeof` does, yes, but he didn't use `typeof` in the first place.