# Javelin - test for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In [Javelin JS](https://github.com/facebook/javelin/blob/master/pkg/javelin.dev.js) - **line 820** , I see a weird test for IE as below

```
// IE does not enter this loop.
for (var i in {toString: 1}) {
  return;
}

// Do IE specific stuff
```

Anyone have an idea as to how reliable this is? Is it relying on a bug?

Edit - It does nothing?

Comment: [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3705407/287185) In short, IE skips `toString` in a for-in loop.

Comment: has it been fixed? I can't seem to replicate it

Comment: Good catch! Guess "IE" should be changed to "old IE" in that code to make it accurate.