# Difference between quirks mode and standards mode JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

Are there any differences in the JavaScript of these two modes in IE 9? If yes, what are they?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. IE9 standards document mode supports [ECMAScript, Fifth Edition features](http://es5.github.com/), so the method such as `forEach`, `every`, `map` of `Array` and `defineProperty`, `keys` of `Object` are support well. [more about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/25/enhanced-scripting-in-ie9-ecmascript-5-support-and-more.aspx)
2. IE9 standards document mode supports enhanced DOM programmability. (may not what you're interested in, but it does so). [more about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/02/dup-exploring-ie9-s-enhanced-dom-capabilities.aspx)
3. IE9 removes some of the key [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679233/are-there-still-ecmascript-3-implementation-differences-in-major-browsers) between IE8 JavaScript implementation and the [ECMAScript, Third Edition Specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/).
4. Quirks mode supports the JavaScript functionality of IE6, It is similar to the behavior of IE5 and the Quirks mode behavior of IE6, IE7 and IE8.
5. Something changed in IE9 Standards Mode, such as [does not support `arguments.caller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622933(v=vs.85)) anymore, [JavaScript Property Enumeration Differs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622937.aspx), and so on. read [Features Changed in Windows Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130950(v=vs.85)) all about this.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there are some differences.

for example, in quirks mode, document.body (the `body`-element) is the root element and in standard mode it's the `html`-element (document.documentElement).

this can have a confusing effect when trying to calculate the viewport dimensions.

Comment: That's difference in DOM, not JavaScript. You'll observe it no matter what scripting engine you'll use.

Comment: that's true but this will surely affect the javascript dom manipulations. I would like to know more differences if possible