# What are the specific differences between IE-5 quirks mode and existing strict standards

Tags: html, refactoring, quirks-mode, internet-explorer-5

I am working on some older software, some of which was written for IE-5 quirks mode. We currently use meta tags to display the code in IE-5 quirks compatibility mode. I am trying to assess the feasibility of refactoring it to a stricter compliance with existing standards.

It will make this job much easier if I can obtain a list of deprecated/nonstandard features present in IE-5 quirks mode. If there is a "IE-5 quirks to HTML 5 strict" dictionary I would consider naming my firstborn after whoever can find it (in lieu of a bounty).

The  closest answers I have been able to find are:

- [difference-between-quirks-mode-and-standards-mode-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410941/difference-between-quirks-mode-and-standards-mode-javascript). Which unfortunately appears to be limited to IE-9 quirks
- [How to force Internet Explorer to view a page in compatability mode (or not)](https://www.thoughtco.com/force-ie-compatibility-mode-3468790) which appears to take more of a scatter-gun approach (I am looking for something a little more comprehensive).