# How to define function and object of same name?

Tags: javascript, function, object, member

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663775/object-name-same-a-function-name), it isn't possible.  But I call bullshit, because the `jQuery` object, for instance, is able to be called as an object with member functions (`jQuery.cookie()`), but also as a function itself (`jQuery('my_selector')`).

How can I achieve the same effect with my objects?  Let's say that I want an *object named* `foo` in the `window` namespace, with a *member function* `bar`, but also a *function named* `foo` in the same `window` namespace as the `foo` *object*.  After declaring such an object-function hybrid, I'll be able to make the following calls:

`window.foo(arg);`

`window.foo.bar(arg);`

Answer (score 3):

A function is also an object:

```
function foo() { /* blah */ }
foo.bar = function () { /* blah */ }
```

Comment: Cool - another syntax q for you, since I don't have privs to post more than once / 25 mins: http://pastehtml.com/view/c6aiy4slm.mrk =)

Comment: `typeof` is an operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof