# What's the purpose of creating jQuery code inside this elements like this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    (function ($) {
       ...
    } ) (jQuery);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024888/a-simple-question-on-jquery-closure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid conflicts with other javascript libraries that also use `$`.

This method, however, allows you to use `$` in that function at your will, no need to use `jQuery` there.

That pattern is also important when writing jquery plugins.

Comment: Thank you very much! All answers and comment enlightened me!

Answer (score 2):

It creates a function, with `$` as an argument, and immediately runs that function with `jQuery` as the argument.  Effectively this will ensure that `$` points to `jQuery` inside your code, even if [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noConflict) is used.

Answer (score 1):

This way, you can use `$` inside your function scope, but on the outside, jQuery is not clobbering other libraries' use of `$` (e.g. Prototype also uses `$`, and some people like to mix the two together)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reason detailed in the other answers, it is (slightly!) faster to access function arguments than global variables.

As long as `jQuery.noConflict()` has not been called, this could be written as `function($){ … }($)` with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Also called a anonymous callback function, as its unbound to any object, so
is strictly 'functional'. A good design pattern when designing plugins with jQuery
to avoid conflicts as others pointed out!