# How do jQuery's namespaces work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean)

I specifically mean when you do this:

```
(function ($) {
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

I've never seen that kind of syntax before. How does the function get called? I understand when you do it like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  ...
});
```

because the function is being passed to jQuery, and jQuery can just run any function passed as a parameter when the DOM's ready, but the first one's different.

Comment: This one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024888/a-simple-question-on-jquery-closure and possibly more.

Comment: Sorry all, I did try searching, but didn't see these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate of [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean/2309648#2309648)

I'll post my answer here, though seeing as Jeff Attwood seems to want us to embrace duplication: (https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

---

This convention is used when writing plugins to ensure there is no confilict with other Javascript libraries using the $ notation, whilst ensuring the plugin author can still use this notataion:

```
(function($){
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

The author is declaring an anonymous function with a single parameter ($), then immediately calling it and passing the jQuery object to it. This ensures the function is called and that everything in it is defined.

A longer notation might be:

```
function MyDefs($){
    ...
}
MyDefs(jQuery);
```

Although that would create a variable MyDefs in the global namespace. The anonymous function pattern leaves the global namespace empty, avoiding conflicts.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh! That's really obvious now you've pointed it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an anonymous function. When you write:

```
(function ($){
  ..
})(jQuery);
```

It is mostly equivalent to:

```
function the_function($) {
  ..
}

the_function(jQuery);
```

The only difference being that the first does not create a function called `the_function` and therefore created no risk of accidentally overwriting an existing function or variable with that name. And of course, all of it is equivalent to:

```
function the_function() {
  var $ = jQuery;
  ..
}

the_function();
```

The point of this construct is that any variables defined inside `the_function` are local and therefore cannot accidentally overwrite any variables or functions in the global scope. For instance, the code inside the function uses `$` to represent the `jQuery` object, but this would conflict with other libraries that use `$` as well (such as Prototype). By wrapping the usage of `$` inside a function, the Prototype code outside the function remains unaffected.