# JavaScript / jQuery closure function syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain the differences between the following functions:

```
(function($){
  // can do something like 
  $.fn.function_name = function(x){};

})(jQuery);
```

Could I use jQuery in the next function?

```
(function(){

}());
```

And is the following the same as jquery.ready()?

```
$(function(){

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [a simple question on jquery closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024888/a-simple-question-on-jquery-closure)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax/4484317#4484317

Comment: Pretty sure the second one should end with `})();`, but I can't edit only 1 character. :(

Comment: @Dan Either way works the same.

Answer (score 101):

---

```
(function($){
  // can do something like 
  $.fn.function_name = function(x){};

})(jQuery);
```

That is self-executing anonymous function that uses `$` in argument so that you can use it (`$`) instead of `jQuery` inside that function and without the fear of conflicting with other libraries because in other libraries too `$` has special meaning. That pattern is especially useful when writing jQuery plugins.

You can write any character there instead of `$` too:

```
(function(j){
  // can do something like 
  j.fn.function_name = function(x){};

})(jQuery);
```

Here `j` will automatically catch up jQuery specified at the end `(jQuery)`. Or you can leave out the argument completely but then you will have to use `jQuery` keyword all around instead of `$` with no fear of collision still. So `$` is wrapped in the argument for short-hand so that you can write `$` instead of `jQuery` all around inside that function.

---

```
(function(){

}());
```

That is self-executing anonymous function again but with no arguments and runs/calls itself because of `()` at the end.

That patterns turns out to be extremely useful in some situations. For example, let's say you want to run a piece of code after 500 milli seconds each time, you would naturally go for `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(doStuff, 500);
```

But what if `doStuff` function takes more than 500 mill-seconds to do what it is doing? You would witness unexpected results but `setInterval` will keep on calling that function again and again at specified time irrespective of whether `doStuff` finished.

That is where that pattern comes in and you can do the same thing with `setTimeout` in combination with self-executing anonymous function and avoid **bad** `setInterval` like this:

```
(function foo(){
   doStuff;

   setTimeout(foo, 500);

})()
```

This code will also repeat itself again and again with one difference. `setTimeout` will never get triggered unless `doStuff` is finished. A much better approach than using bad `setInterval`.

[You can test it here.](http://jsbin.com/usali4)

Note that you can also write self-executing anonymous function like this:

```
function(){
  // some code
}();
```

Using extra braces around (like before `function` keyword) is simply **coding convention** and can be seen in Crackford's writings, jQuery and elsewhere.

---

```
$(function(){

});
```

That is short-hand syntax for ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

**More Information:**

- [How Self-Executing Anonymous Functions Work](http://briancrescimanno.com/2009/09/24/how-self-executing-anonymous-functions-work/)

Comment: Note further that `jQuery(someFunction)` passes the jQuery object as the first argument to the callback. This allows you to do this slightly-safer-but-still-terse version of the document ready handler: `jQuery(function($){ ...use $ here without fear of global collision... });`

Comment: Expect for the cause of the `setTimeout` benefit I personally  file this in the 'anti-pattern' category. For the sake of brevity it is not worth losing in code clarity, IDE code assist, and debugging; I'll leave the code shortening to automatic minification tools.

Comment: `function() {  /* Some code */ }();` Is actually **not** valid syntax.

Answer (score 10):

I know that this question is old, but I stumbled upon it right now and so may other people. I just wanted to point out that, although Sarfraz's answer is great, it has to be said that no, writing a **self-executing, anonymous function** within braces is **not** a *coding convention*.

```
function(){
  // some code
}();
```

Will not work and give out a `SyntaxError` because the function is being parsed as a `FunctionDeclaration`, and the function name **is not optional** in this case.

On the other hand, the [Grouping Operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.6) makes sure that the content is evaluated as a `FunctionExpression`.

**See:** [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/)