# What do parenthesis after curly braces mean?

Tags: javascript

I have seen Javascript code that uses parenthesis immediately after a function's closing curly brace, I can't understand what they're used for.

Example:

```
function foo(bar){
  return bar;
}(0);
```

- What does `(0)` do?
- What is this called?
- When should you use this technique?

Comment: If you just provided a bad example, then your question is a duplicate of [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, you simply have two statements and it is equivalent to:

```
function foo(bar){
  return bar;
}
0;
```

This is **not** a self-invoking function. The first statement is a **function declaration**, the second statement is simply the number literal `0`, which does not do anything. The parenthesis don't execute the function, they are the [grouping operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.6).

How can we prove this? Try:

```
function foo(bar){
  return "bar";
}(0);
```

and tell me what the output is.

---

It would be a self-invoking function, if we had a **function expression**. For that you can use the grouping operator to force it being evaluated as expression.

For example:

```
(function foo(bar){
  return bar;
})(0);
```

This is a named function expression. The result of the expression (`(function ....)`) is a function reference, and `(0)` executes the function, passing `0` as argument.

The position of the parenthesis could also be:

```
(function foo(bar){
  return bar;
}(0));
```

Maybe this is what you have seen.

This technique was already extensively discussed here: [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you Felix, you must have eagle eyes :)

Answer (score 12):

They immediately invoke the function similar to when you call a function:

```
function foo() {
   alert('hello');
}

foo(); // call
```

You can also call it **directly**:

```
(function foo(){
   alert('hello');
})(); // <--------------
```

---

Currently you have  `Function Declaration`. ***To actually self-invoke it***, you need to have it like this in **parenthesis** (to make it an expression):

```
(function foo(bar){
  return bar;
})(0);
```

And now it is `Function Expression` and will invoke immediately. To know difference between `Function Declaration` and `Function Expression`, check out this excellent article by [Kangax](http://perfectionkills.com):

- [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

---

> What does (0) do?

It is argument passed to `foo` function so `bar` would be `0` inside function.

> What is this called?

It is a self-inovking or self-executing function. You may also want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472528/javascript-jquery-closure-function-syntax/4472589#4472589).

> When should you use this technique?

When you want to invoke a function straight away and keep variable scope inside that function expression only. It won't be available to outside world or rather the code outside that function expression.

---

**Learn More:**

- [Self-invoking functions explained line by line](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2011/08/22/self-invoking-functions-explained-line-by-line/)

Comment: Tip: `(function (...){ ... })(...);` works every time, even with anonymous functions, where the return value isn't assigned to a var

Comment: This is not correct unfortunately. See my answer. But maybe the OP only gave a bad example.

Comment: @FelixKling: +1 to you. I overlooked the OP's syntax, added more details.

Comment: I can confirm Felix and the parenthesis after de curly bracket does not call the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a self invoking function. You passing 0 as a parameter. Therefore your function will be returning bar which equals 0.

For eg the below function is the equivalent:

```
function foo(bar) {
    return bar;
}

foo(0); // returns 0
```