# Value of variable not changing predictably within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

My javascript loop is not working properly. I am getting only the final value of `$i`.

```
$(function() {
    var $count = $('#count').val();
    for (var $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        var btnRemove = $('#removeImage' + $i);
        var profilepictureid = $('#profilePitcureID' + $i).val();
        btnRemove.click(function() {
            alert($i);
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time your `click` event handler executes, `$i` has reached it's final value (`$count - 1`). You need to capture the value of `$i` at each iteration of the loop. You can do this by introducing a closure that "closes over" the value of `$i` at each iteration:

```
for(var $i=1; $i<$count; $i++) {
    var btnRemove=$('#removeImage'+$i); 
    var profilepictureid = $('#profilePitcureID'+$i).val();

    (function ($i) {
        btnRemove.click(function(){
            alert($i);
        });
    }($i));
}
```

Comment: @Mansoor: just for supplement, check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472528/javascript-jquery-closure-function-syntax, for explanation what jquery closure function syntax is (unless you already know) - that's what I did after reading this answer