# getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when call controller function with ajax in magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have created custom module in admin with the name **createadmincontroller** module and it configure the config.xml.i want to call the controller index function from .phtml with ajax but it throw an error "**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**"
can any one tell me where I went wrong? below is my full module details:

my code is:

JR->CreateAdminController->controllers->Adminhtml->CustomController.php

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
echo 'successful';
//exit;
}
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
        ->_title($this->__('Index Action'));



    $this->renderLayout();
}
?>
```

JR->CreateAdminController->etc->config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <JR_CreateAdminController>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </JR_CreateAdminController>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <jr_createadmincontroller>
            <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
            <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
        </jr_createadmincontroller>
    </helpers>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <jr_createadmincontroller before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</jr_createadmincontroller>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
<layout>
    <updates>
  <petra>
      <file>createadmincontroller.xml</file>
     </petra>
 </updates>   
</layout>
</adminhtml>
```

app->design->adminhtml->default->default->layout->createadmincontroller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<adminhtml_custom_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="createadmincontroller" template="createadmincontroller/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_custom_index>
</layout>
```

app->design->adminhtml->default->default->template->createadmincontroller->index.phtml

```
<button type="button" class="scalable" onclick="test()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
function test(){
alert("wao");   
var t = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/custom');   ?>';
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/custom/'); ?>"

        }).done(function() {
            alert("Hey");
        });
}
</script>
```

JR->CreateAdminController->Helper->Data.php

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{} 
?>
```

Comment: two things to correct yet : bad habit you should really loose is to close php on a class. You should never ever do this. please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag
Another thing is using $_POST. Magento has built in functionalities for that, inherited from ZF. Instead please use `$this->getRequest()->getPost('data');`

Comment: how i call index function from controller by ajax.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try tu use `jQuery.ajax()` instead of `$.ajax()`?

Magento uses Prototype JS, which has already claimed the `$` global variable. So you need to use [jQuery in no-conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode and use `jQuery` instead.

**Alternatives**

1. Use `$j.ajax()` after applying no-conflict mode with `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` *(thanks @b.enoit.be)*
2. Wrap your jQuery code inside a closure: `(function($){ .... $.ajax() .... })(jQuery);` *(also see here [JavaScript / jQuery closure function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472528/javascript-jquery-closure-function-syntax))*

**Adding jQuery to Magento**

Change your layout XML file `createadmincontroller.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_custom_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/jquery-1.x.x.js</script>
            </action>
            <block type="core/text" name="jquery.noconflict">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
                    </text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="createadmincontroller" template="createadmincontroller/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custom_index>
</layout>
```

Also see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53905/3326

Comment: Alternatively you can shorten the use to $j.ajax() because of the `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` in `js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js` :)

Comment: @7ochem now getting "jQuery is not defined"

Comment: @7ochem also i already used no conflict but still getting the error.

Comment: @b.enoit.be i already used no conflict but still getting the error.

Comment: @Priyank what is your version of Magento ? jQuery only comes recently bundled in Magento, so maybe you are in a version where you don't have it ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be i have ver 1.7.0.2.so how to include new jquery in my module.becoz when ever in include jquery in my .pthml file like this "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://172.20.5.88/fashionelements/js/jquery.js"></script>" it throw an error.plz help in this

Comment: @7ochem can you explain how to add for js for particular page as mention here "http://www.magesolution.com/blog/how-to-add-jquery-in-magento/". i want to add js in my senario.plz explain

Comment: @Priyank, I've updated my answer to explain how to add jQuery

Comment: @7ochem hey!! thanks for your update.but still not working and also now my admin module page looks blank.may be i did some thing wrong.please explain me or if free come for chat :)

Comment: @7ochem sorry dude.it's my fault.your code is works absolutely fine :) i accept & upvote your answer.thanks :)