# JavaScript WordPress uncaught typeerror $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".showhide").click(function(){
      $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

I'm not a JavaScript programmer. I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError $ is not a function`

For some reason my navigation is not working.
Someone told me to put this in JavaScript but I'm getting the error.

Found this: `jQuery(document);` but don't know how to use this.

Comment: You need to make sure jQuery is imported.

Comment: Try replacing `$` for the word `jQuery`, so instead of `$(document)` you will use `jQuery(document)`, sometimes, other JS libraries use `$` and it is common that in wordpress environments you have several JS libraries.

Comment: as Pointy said, you probably don't have jQuery included

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it specially on WordPress (since Wordpress is usually using `jQuery` instead of `$`)

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".showhide").click(function(){
      $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
   });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472528/javascript-jquery-closure-function-syntax)

or if you don't like the answer above, you can add `var $ = jQuery;` before the `$(document).ready` function

Comment: This is more verbose than necessary, particularly since you are wrapping in a document ready also.  Can be consolidated down to simply `jQuery(function($) { .... });`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that WordPress uses jQuery [in compatibility mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), which means that it does NOT utilize the `$` by default.

You CAN use the `$` to access jQuery, but you just need to wrap it in a document ready function.

Here's the simplest way to do this:

```
// By passing the $ as a function argument, $ is available anywhere inside this document ready function
jQuery(function($) {
   // Do all your $ jQuery goodness in here...
   $(".showhide").click(function(){
      $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
   });
   // $ is available until the end of the document ready
});
// Outside of the document ready function - now you cannot use $ - you'd have to use jQuery....
jQuery('.showhide').click(....);
```

For completeness sake, be sure you have [enqueued](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) jQuery.

In your theme's `functions.php` file, or in your plugin's main file, add this:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

This ensures that jQuery is loaded - **the right way** - in your WordPress site.

Comment: You don't actually need to wrap things in a `ready` function (in fact, doing so may be unnecessary if the JS code comes at the end of the document body). You can use a simple self-invoking function instead.

Comment: @mevius - True, but this is the most convenient way to get jQuery accessible via the `$`, and in most cases, a document ready is useful / required.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jQuery` instead of `$` if you still gets the error do as following.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function(){
   j(".showhide").click(function(){
      j("nav").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```