# scrollreveal.min.js error, only on index page of website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking at different forums that include this error and trying different things that I have read to get rid of this error. I have tried removing any duplicate libraries, and changing the order in which they appear, but nothing has seemed to worked for me. I am using a bootstrap theme

```
scrollreveal.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'sequence' of 
undefined
 at e.reveal (scrollreveal.min.js:1)
 at jquery.js:53
 at jquery.js:75
```

I am not sure what to do to get rid of it, any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Below is what I have in the head section

```
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Plugin CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="./css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

And this is what I have at the end of the body.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollReveal.js/3.3.6/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
<script src="js/creative.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **1)** Are those the same for the index page **and** the other pages? What could be different? **2)** Is `js/jquery.js` another jQuery library or really a custom JS strangely named?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yea they are. That is a custom js file

Comment: Is that possible that you instantiate `scrollReveal` on an element that is not present on the buggy page, in your custom JS files?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No, it is on the index page. This is my bootstrap -
 https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/ and currently the phone and envelope are not appearing

Comment: Is there errors in [the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337)?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes the error above is shown in the console

Comment: okay... So nothing else. mmm Do you have a live link to provide here?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It is for uni and don't want to send it publicly over the internet. Do you have discord?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it is a working progress, so some links may not work. Just to let you know :)

Comment: On line#75 of jquery.js, try to replace `})(jQuery); // End of use strict` by `}); // End of use strict`

Comment: Okay... Now the same on line #82 and line #157

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette still getting the same error, I am working off the link I gave you so you will be able to see the up to date version

Comment: Not the same error... Notice it fired elsewhere!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette its the same error for me, strange! Will try in a diffrerent browser. Line 175 is  var length = requiredLength - str.length; what do I change on this line? Deleted (jquery) from line 82

Comment: Yes... It mistyped the 157 the first time... lol

Comment: okay... One left again on line #164

Comment: Yeah... no error now.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yea, cleared the cache and the error updated and then realised what the errors meant :) Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Explanations about your issue can be read in [**this detailled SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472589/2159528) It was not an easy one to find... In the future, look what is on the line where the error fired. That is the last displayed in the "stack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not "self explanatory"...

But the line where the error fired, line #75 of `jquery.js` *(A custom JS file, not the library)*, was containing a closure syntax: `})(jQuery);` that was not needed.

Replacing it by `});` fixed the issue for that line.

Then, the same issue fired on 3 other lines... But after those lines also fixed, the page worked as expected without error.

**"Closure" itself is already well explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472589/2159528).**