# what is( function($){.....})(jQuery) that often used in the making of jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [a simple question on jquery closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024888/a-simple-question-on-jquery-closure)

I often see the code of jquery plugin consist this code, Can I know what it is? and what the purpose for?

Comment: How many questions about this have been asked the past week?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing little about jQuery, but something about JavaScript, I'd guess this declares an anonymous function that receives one argument (accessible using `$` in the body of the function) and immediately calls this function, passing the `jQuery` object as argument.

Answer (score 0):

How jQuery plugins usually work is that they make a function that adds the plugin to jQuery, and then immediately call that function so the plugin is installed. The notation

```
(function($) { ..code... })(jQuery)
```

makes a nameless function and then calls that function, passing the jQuery object as an argument. And then somewhere in the code of that function, you should find a

```
$.fn.newPlugin = ...
```

This adds the plugin into jQuery. This is done so that no conflicts are created; using this notation, no function names or variable names are actually declared.