# What is the difference between these two functions/approaches?

Tags: javascript, function

I use only jQuery for writing JavaScript code. One thing that confuses me is these two approaches of writing functions,

**First approach**

```
vote = function (action,feedbackId,responseDiv)
{
    alert('hi');
    return feedbackId;
}
```

**Second approach**

```
function vote(action, feedbackId,responseDiv)
{
    alert('hi');
    return feedbackId;
}
```

What is the difference between the two and why should one use the first approach or the second approach?

Comment: Unless `vote` has already been declared, `vote = function (action,feed...` should be `var vote = function (action,feed...`—it's bad practice to use implied globals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is a *function expression* assigned to the `vote` variable, the second is a *function declaration*.

The main difference is that function statements are evaluated at parse time, they are available *before* its declaration at runtime.

See also:

- [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) (article)
- [Explain JavaScript’s encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321)

Answer (score 6):

```
function myFunction() {}
```

...is called a "function declaration".

```
var myFunction = function() {};
```

...is called a "function expression".

They're very similar; however:

- The function declaration can be declared *after* it is referenced, whereas the function expression must be declared before it is referenced:

  ```
  // OK
  myFunction();
  function myFunction() {}

  // Error
  myFunction();
  var myFunction = function() {};
  ```
- Since a function expression is a statement, it should be followed by a semi-colon.

See [Function constructor vs. function declaration vs. function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression) at the [Mozilla Developer Centre](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a function expression,

```
var calculateSum = function(a, b) { return a + b; }

alert(calculateSum(5, 5)); // Alerts 10
```

The second one is a plain function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration syntax cannot be used within a block statement.

Legal:

```
function a() {
    function b() {

    }
}
```

Illegal:

```
function a() {
    if (c) {
        function b() {

        }
    }
}
```

You can do this though:

```
function a() {
    var b;
    if (c) {
        b = function() {

        };
    }
}
```