# Difference between JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between these two functions/approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160420/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-functions-approaches)

I've seen various types of functions posted around but I can't seem to find the answer to the differences between them. I know how to write these two but I don't know the difference.

```
function aFunction() {

}

var aFunction = function() {

}
```

Then I've heard of things like closures, amongst other different names. I'm new to programming sorry, could someone tell me all the different types and the differences between them?