# What is the difference between these two particular JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The difference between the two functions? (“function x” vs “var x = function”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114525/the-difference-between-the-two-functions-function-x-vs-var-x-function)
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

```
var test = function() {
    var a = 20;
    var b = 30;

    return a + b;
};

function Add() {
    var a = 20;
    var b = 30;

    return a + b;
}
```

What is the difference between these two functions? If I call add() or test() they both give me the same result. What exactly does the `var` do?

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160420/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-functions-approaches

Comment: @KendallFrey: don't edit in a possible dupe message.

Comment: If you're downvoting this post because it's a dupe, consider that it wasn't originally posted in stackoverflow, and thus the O.P. wouldn't have been able to search for dupes as easily as you might think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function declaration syntax cannot be used within a block statement.

Legal:

```
function a() {
    function b() {

    }
}
```

Illegal:

```
function a() {
    if (c) {
        function b() {

        }
    }
}
```

You can do this though:

```
function a() {
    var b;
    if (c) {
        b = function() {

        };
    }
}
```

For the language nerds among us you'll want to reference sections 12.1, 13.1, and 14 of the specification. You will find the following syntax descriptions.

**12.1  Block**

**Syntax**

Block : 
    **{** StatementList<sub>opt</sub> **}**

StatementList : 
    Statement 
    StatementList Statement

**13  Function Definition**

**Syntax**

FunctionDeclaration : 
 
    **function** Identifier **(** FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub> **) {** FunctionBody **}**

FunctionExpression : 
 
    **function** Identifier<sub>opt</sub> **(** FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub> **) {** FunctionBody **}**

FormalParameterList : 
 
    Identifier 
 
    FormalParameterList **,** Identifier

FunctionBody : 
 
    SourceElements

**14  Program**

**Syntax**

Program : 
 
    SourceElements<sub>opt</sub>

SourceElements : 
 
    SourceElement 
 
    SourceElements SourceElement

SourceElement : 
 
    Statement 
 
    FunctionDeclaration

Comment: My gaffe aside, is this explicitly declared illegal in the ECMA-262 spec, and if so, where?

Comment: @kojiro - Yes of course let me include that.

Comment: @kojiro - Took a healthy mix of markdown and html but I've included the syntax for the lazy. :)

Answer (score 1):

They're different.
If you call the function declared with a var before declaration, it will throw an error since it hasn't been declared yet.

```
test(); // Undefined
var test = function() {
    ...
};
```

This can be called however at any time and defined at run time.

```
test(); // OK
function test() {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case you have an anonymous function assigned to a name, and in the second, a function declaration. In most cases, this difference doesn't matter. Where it does matter is

1. in debuggers, a named function can sometimes be more easily identified in stack traces and
2. variable hoisting causes the *entire* function declaration to be "moved" to the top of its containing function, so

   foo(1, 2);
   var foo = function (a, b) {
       return a+b;
   }

is equivalent to

```
var foo;
foo(1, 2);
foo = function (a, b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

(you can see why it would fail.)

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Add() before the its definition, but you can't invoke test() before its definition.

Also see [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

Answer (score 0):

The `var` means you are assigning a variable to an anonymous function. If you were going to assign your function to a variable, you would do this:

```
var test = function Add() {
    var a = 20;
    var b = 30;

    return a + b;
};
```

You have to name the function that you are using.

You don't have to assign a function to a variable, but if you would like to keep the data from the function then you should assign the function to a variable, so you would use the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The first function you are assigning is an anonymous function to a variable test variable. Then variable test becomes the test() function.