# What this mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

I have just read a javascript book but I have seen this code:

```
1(function() {

          // code

})();
```

what is this ? is a special function ?

Comment: Where did that `1` and that `};` come from? They don't look like they belong.

Comment: I have correct now :) .... that 1 is likely the name of the function but I don't know.

Comment: a typo? book editors are not infallible :D

Comment: 1 is probably the number of the example in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, it has a syntax error.

I'm guessing it was more like:

```
(function() {
          // code
})();
```

or

```
(function() {
          // code
    }
)();
```

Break it down:

```
(FOO)() // calls FOO with no arguments.
```

And

```
function() { //creates a function that takes no arguments.
      // code
}
```

Hence together it would create a function that takes no arguments, and then call it. I can't see why you would apart from just showing that you can.

Comment: You do so in JavaScript to create a protected scope.  `var` s defined in that block will not be accessible in the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the intent was to declare the function inline/anonymous and immediately execute it.