# Anonymous JavaScript function for global abatement

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've run across some strangeness in JavaScript syntax that I don't understand.

I was trying to use a single anonymous global function for global abatement, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function() {
    alert("all code goes here");
  }();
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I get a syntax error.  This fixes it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var MAIN = function() {
    alert("all code goes here");
  }();
</script>
```

But is unsatisfying because there is now a global `MAIN` object.  Then I ran across this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    alert("all code goes here");
  })();
</script>
```

A colleague of mine saw this, shook his head and said "that's some syntax man".

What is going on with

`var x = function() { .. }();`

that requires parenthesis without the variable like this

`(function() { ... })();`

Edit: Identical to another question, with this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321).

Comment: That's not a closure. Closures != anonymous functions.

Comment: @delnan Thanks, edited the title.  An explanation of what's going on would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `function() {}()` is being parsed as a *function declaration*. In a function declaration the function name is mandatory, so since it's missing here you get a syntax error. Placing parentheses around the `function() {}()` fixes the problem by forcing the code inside to be parsed as an expression instead: the parentheses act as the *grouping operator*, within which only an expression is valid.

Placing `function() {}()` on the right hand side of an assignment works for a similar reason: only an expression is valid there, so the function is parsed as an expression.

This is a short explanation. If you want a longer version, I'd suggest reading [CMS's excellent explanation in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321).

Comment: Thanks for passing this on.  It's too bad that the answer is "because the grammar says so."  I would guess that's it's hard to get this stuff right when designing a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1):

Basically... Javascript requires you to put your function somewhere.

You can do this with the normal named syntax:

```
function foo(){}
```

Or with the variable assignment syntax:

```
var foo = function(){}
```

The syntax with the `()` is actually just the second syntax, but you throw away the result instead of storing it somewhere.

This is actually equivalent to the statement above:

```
var foo = (function(){})
```

But since you can't have an assignment without assigning it to something it won't work without the `()`.

Comment: I think I get it, but let me try to clarify.  Essentially `function() {}` all by itself doesn't produce a function value because it is unevaluated.  But `var x = function() {}` and `function x() {}` do.  That means that `var x = function() {}` really does some converting into the latter form, rather than first evaluating the right hand side and passing the result to x.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Rich: that's pretty much how I understand it. `function() {}` is a declaration for a new function object that creates the function when evaluated. When storing it in a variable it will be evaluated or when passes as an argument or when evaluated as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason is basically to disambiguate between a function declaration and a function expression.

If the extra braces or variable introduction don't sit well with you, there's always an operator you can persuade to do the work for you:

```
void function() {
    alert('hi');
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var foo = function(){alert("call");}();
var foo2 = function(){alert("call");};
console.log(foo2);
console.log(foo);

//foo(); //<-bad, foo not a function
console.log(function(){return "json";}());
</script>
```

var foo is undefined cause there is no return value;
if we do this:

```
var foo = function(){return function(){alert("call");};}();
foo(); //works cause a function is assigned to foo
```

Comment: Right, but that's not what I'm after.  Essentially, I'm putting my page's JavaScript code inside the function and want it called once.  That way I don't pollute the global namespace with extra variables.  In your example, I wouldn't care that `foo` is not a function, but I needed it there to trigger the alert when the page loaded.

Comment: "Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object." from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function. if you want to trigger the alert when the page loaded, you might want to use"window.load= function(){...}"

Comment: Thanks.  My question was why the `function() {}();` syntax didn't work. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321) is why.  :)