# Why does a Javascript function act differently upon instantiation than execution?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm coming from C#/PHP and trying to get my head around Javascript's idea that functions are variables/objects and have quasi constructors, etc.

Can anyone explain why the following code functions as it does, namely:

1. Why isn't "2" displayed when instantiating the variable/function `test`?
2. Why isn't "1" displayed when executing the variable/function `test`?

code:

```
var setup = function () {
    console.log(1);
    return function() {
        console.log(2);
    };
};

var test = setup(); // 1
test(); // 2
test(); // 2
test(); // 2
```

## added:

Thanks @thejh @Justin so the function is returning a *completely different function* that has nothing to do with the first (I was thinking of the second function as a kind of constructor of the first), if I comment it out, it's clearer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var setup = function () {
        console.log(1);
//        return function() {
//            console.log(2);
//        };
    };

    var test = setup(); // 1
    test(); // "test is not a function"
    test(); // "test is not a function"
    test(); // "test is not a function"

});
```

Comment: Heavily discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax

Comment: Not mine, but OOP in JS is a fantastic read to wrap your hand on how the prototype based JS deals with these things.
http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html

Comment: @your edit The `function()` syntax is just a prettier way of calling `new Function()`. So it's perfectly natural and expected that a new Function instance will be created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only calling `setup()` the first time. Once it is called, the new function it returns is assigned to `test`. From there on, you're calling that new function:

```
// calls setup which logs 1 and returns a new function.
// setup also returns a new function and assigns that new function to test.
var test = setup(); 

// test now is the equivalent of var test = function(){ console.log(2); };

// call the new function that setup returned which logs 2
test();

// and again
test();

// and again
test();
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you're returning a *different* function from what gets called when creating it (the one in the `return`, one you're not calling on the first line)...*that*'s what gets executed on the other calls.  For example this would give you `1` then `2`:

```
var test = setup()(); // 1, 2
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UqP4h/).

Answer (score 1):

In your first assignment of test to setup(), you're executing the whole function, so `console.log(1)` runs, then returns a new function.

Now, you're assigning the return value of that first function to be the next function that runs `console.log(2)`, so now test references that returned function.

Your subsequent calls just run that function which runs `console.log(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setup()` prints `1` and returns a reference to that anonymous function. Calling that prints `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine instead of

```
var setup = function () {
    console.log(1);
    return function() {
        console.log(2);
    }
}
```

this equivalent [OOP syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
var setup = new Function("\
    console.log(1);\
    return new Function(\"\
        console.log(2);\
    \");\
");
var test = setup(); // 1
test(); // 2
test(); // 2
test(); // 2
```

I think things should be more familiar to you now.

Answer (score 1):

Hello when you do `setup()` you execute this two lines :

```
console.log(1);
function() { console.log(2); }
```

- the first line log "1"
- the second line doesn't log any thing, because the function is not called, it only create an object (and this object is a function).

when you do `test()` you actually call the function you've created and so you log "2"

JS is a functional language, you have to see functions like first citizen object.