# "this" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the syntax of how to put together a JavaScript function as an object.

Q: Is this the right way to do it?

The reason why I ask is because I'm looking at it in Firebug and I was hoping to be able to drill down and see the value of myVar and myVariable, but instead Firebug only says that "this" is an object Object.

```
var myObject = {
    init: function() {
        var myVar = 1;
        myObject.myVariable = 2;
        console.log('"this" when called as an object: ' + this);
    }
}
myObject.init();
```

Also, what's the funny little syntax to call it directly upon declaration?  Something about (), but when I remove the last line and put () at the end of the declaration, I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create a string:

```
'"this" when called as an object: ' + this
```

But `this` is not a string, so its toString() prototype gets called. That's why you only see `[object Object]`.

If you want to have Firebug display the actual object, do a simple `console.log(this)` or to see the contents directly use `console.dir(this)`.

Comment: By replacing + with a comma, I was able to see "this" in a much better light.  Thanks Wetzel!

Answer (score 2):

The "funny little syntax" doesn't really apply here, because you're not really creating a "function object" — that's just an object with a property whose value is a reference to a function object.

However, though it's been done to death on Stackoverflow, you're probably talking about something like this:

```
var myobject = (function() {
  var something = { whatever: "for example" };
  return {
    init: function() {
      this.foo = "hello";
      // initialize
    },
    getSomething: function() { return something.whatever; }
  };
})();
```

Now "myobject" is initialized by a call to an anonymous function, which will be thrown away right after that statement. The *closure* formed by the function invocation, however, remains alive.

Comment: "though it's been done to death on Stackoverflow".
<p>
I'm not sure I even know how to frame the question so that I can see similar questions.</p>

Comment: Well I tried a question about "this" and the SO search thing found [this old question about immediately-invoked anonymous functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice reference for [JavaScript object creation](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)