# What is the difference between x = function(a, b, c){} and function x(a, b, c){}?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Is there any difference between these two ways of declaring a function?

Comment: The second one, I think you meant `function x(a,b,c){}`, because `function(a,b,c){}` will just simply cause a `SyntaxError` when used in *statement context*, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax) and [this possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that post when I posted this one :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both anonymous functions, only one is assigned to a variable named `x`.

I think you may be trying to refer to what is known as [function expressions and function declarations](http://javascript.info/tutorial/functions-declarations-and-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

`x = function(a, b, c){}` assigns the function to the alias `x` so you would execute it using `x(a, b, c)`. The second is an anonymous function that would not be accessible after the place that it was declared as it is not assigned to anything.