# What is the difference between (function(){ /* ... */ })(); and (function(){ /* ... */ }());

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(…()) vs. (…)() in javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774425/vs-in-javascript-closures)

Is there any difference between (function(){ ... })(); and (function(){ ... }()); ?

In this example both works the same way:

```
window.onload=function() {

    var a = (function(i){
        return "aaa" + i;
    })(1);


    var b = (function(i){
        return "bbb" + i;
    }(2));

    console.log("a: "+ a);
    console.log("b: "+ b);

};
```

Comment: No difference, just a manner of writing. Both are versions of a **self-executing anonymous function** (or, Immediately Invoked Function Expression if you so prefer).

Comment: Yeah I hate the "self-executing" bit. They are no more "self-executing" than any other piece of Javascript code.

Comment: I think the term that is more accepted term is [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).  (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)