# Differences between (func(){}()); vs (func(){})();

Tags: javascript

I commonly see both conventions and I'm wondering if there's an actual difference.

```
(function () {
  document.write("it works");
}());

(function () {
  document.write("it also works");
})();
```

Comment: Oh yes, the infamous "dog balls"! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774425/vs-in-javascript-closures and the links therein.

Comment: I guess (func(){}()); did not hit all of those search results.

Answer (score 1):

There no difference between the two ,
The opening brace serves as a syntactic hint to tell the parser that what follows is a function expression instead of a function declaration.

for more http://jsperf.com/self-invoking-function