# Self Executing Anonymous Function Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, self-executing-function

I often write my JS self executing anonymous functions like this

```
(function(){})()
```

but the other day I saw this, in somebody's code

```
(function(){}())
```

what's the difference, and is one recommended over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)

Comment: and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774425/vs-in-javascript-closures

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(){}());
```

I recommended this one, because it makes more sense.

You have your function `function(){}` then you append the `()` to execute it, then you wrap the whole thing in `()` to specify that it's an expression. That is done so the js interpreter will not define it as a function declarations, but as a function expression.

But it doesn't matter, it will execute properly, so it's a personal taste problem.