# what is the difference in two test1 and test2 javascript snippets?

Tags: javascript

Here are two javascript snippets. i can't understand thedifferent between the two. it seems both allow newing up instances.

```
var Test1 = (function () {
            function Test1(_x, _y) {
                this.x = _x;
                this.y = _y; console.log("test1");
            }
            return Test1;
        }());
var Test2 = function () {
            function Test2(_x, _y) {
                this.x = _x;
                this.y = _y; console.log("test2");
            }
            return Test2;
        }();

new Test1(1,2); 
new Test2(2,4);
```

Edit: it looks the same to me BUT, i was poking around with TypeScript and it generated the classes like Type1. there must be a reason they chose to go with that. after all the shortest code is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. In both cases you have self-invoking function, but in case 1 it is surrounded by parentheses which actually do nothing since there is already an IIFE and there is no more scope to hide.

The difference is just like between these two:

```
var var1 = 1 + 3;
var var2 = (1 + 3);
```

Talking about IIFE decoration, I would recommended to use the following syntax:

```
var Test2 = (function () {
    function Test2(_x, _y) {
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y; console.log("test2");
    }
    return Test2;
})();
```

It does the same thing too, but it seems to be a commonly-used and prevalent syntax.

If TypeScript generates such code, it doesn't mean that it is done on any special purpose.
Probably, it is just how TypeScript compiler interprets a context scope and surrounds it with parantheses by default no matter whether it is necessary in this case or not.

Comment: "*it is recommended to use the following syntax … and de-facto standard.*" - How did you gather that?

Comment: @Bergi It is my own experience :) I have rarely seen other usages. Just to support my words with a *proof*, I have found a [popular question about IIFEs at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), and 95% of answers are using this approach. I will edit my answer and won't use this too assertive sentence. Thank you for correction :)

Comment: It's really [purely opinion-based](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774506/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

Putting parentheses around a function statement forces it into expression context so it is a function expression instead of a function declaration.

However, putting a function statement on the right hand side of a `=` does that already, so in this case it makes no difference at all.