# Can somebody explain following java script code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was recently going through the typescript documentations

reference: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

in this documentation, there is similar `typescript` code related to section `classes` as follows

```
class Student {
  fullName: string;
  constructor(public firstName: string) {
    this.fullName = firstName;
  }
}
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
}
function greeter(person : Person) {
  return "Hello, " + person.firstName;
}
let user = new Student("Jane");
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

I `compiled` this code with `tsc filename.ts`
It's giving me a javascript compiled code as

```js
var Student = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Student(firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.fullName = firstName;
    }
    return Student;
}());
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName;
}
var user = new Student("Jane");
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

In this generated javascript code I want to know this part:

```
var Student = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Student(firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.fullName = firstName;
    }
    return Student;
}());
```

I want someone to help me with good references for Javascript basics for this.

Comment: first line and last two lines are superfluous - basically the code is wrapped in an IIFE for no discernible reason

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize I have a gold hammer in JavaScript, sorry Krishnan. Either way, what you're looking at is a immediately invoked function expression. Details can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript.

Comment: @Bravo — Since it is automated code generation, the IIFE is probably there to locally scope the methods (of which in this example there are zero) instead of making globals.

Comment: @Quentin - I understand, I was explaining that particular code and trying to remove the mystifying part

Comment: Hey thanks to all @Bravo, your keyword `IIFE` helped me

Comment: @Zeta your reference helped me, however, I also found this as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774425/vs-in-javascript-closures that cleared me the concept