# "this" refers to something else?

Tags: javascript

When I run this code:

```
var Test = function() {
    return this.stuff;
};

Test.stuff = 'Neat!';

document.write(Test() || 'Not neat.');
```

Why do I get 'Not neat.'? Why can't I access the stuff property using `this.stuff`?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While other people have posted why this occurs (the understanding of `this` is incorrect), here is one solution which will work reliably.

*Update:* As Raynos noted, [when using strict mode functions](http://es5.github.com/#C) in ECMAScript 5th Edition, it is invalid to use `arguments.callee` (it will throw a TypeError). Thus caution should be exercised if using this approach. (When using a [correct] ECMAScript 5th edition engine, there is no reason to use `arguments.callee` over the name given to the function which is bound to the new scope -- see the end of the answer.)

```
var Test = function() {
   // arguments.callee is the current function, if any
   return arguments.callee.stuff
}
Test.stuff = 'Neat!'
alert(Test() || 'Not neat.') // Neat!
```

Another is to use a closure:

```
var Test = (function () {
  function fn () {
    // closure over fn, which names this function-object
    return fn.stuff
  }
  fn.stuff = 'Neat!' // here
  return fn          // do not combine with function declaration!
})()
Test.stuff = 'Neat!' // or here
alert(Test() || 'Not neat.') // Neat!
```

Or, a closure over a variable directly:

```
var Test = (function () {
  var stuff = 'Neat!'
  return function () {
    // variable closure, no property
    return stuff
  }
})()
alert(Test() || 'Not neat.') // Neat!
```

Or... so many ways.

Happy coding.

---

Another approach that was pointed out by Aadit M Shah is to use the function identifier to refer to the current function:

```
var Test = function Temp () {
   return Temp.stuff
}
Test.stuff = 'Neat!'
alert(Test() || 'Not neat.') // Neat! (But see below.)
```

As Aadit points out, this is valid, as per the [ECMAScript 5th edition specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), page 99:

> *The Identifier in a FunctionExpression can be referenced from inside the FunctionExpression's FunctionBody  to 
>   allow the function to call itself recursively.* However, unlike in a FunctionDeclaration, the  Identifier  in a FunctionExpression cannot be referenced from and does not affect the scope enclosing the FunctionExpression.

However, *some browsers (at least IE9) implements this incorrectly* (and I am not sure if the above noted behavior is well-defined in the 3rd edition). Consider:

```
var x = function y () { return y }; y = 42; x();
```

In IE9 it will yield 42 and in FF8 it will yield the function-object. IE9 is *incorrect here* as it introduces `y` as a variable in the *enclosing* scope, which is forbidden by ECMAScript for function expressions. Here is an in-context example of how this incorrect implementation can lead to different results:

```
var Test = function Temp () {
   return Temp.stuff
}
Test.stuff = "Neat!"
Temp = {}
alert(Test() || 'Not neat.') // 'Not neat.' in IE9, 'Neat!' in FF8
```

Comment: What would be the difference between using arguments.callee and just repeating the function name directly?

Comment: @missingno Preference? :) I have used both, depending on what I wanted to do and how "it fit" with the rest of the code. I cannot come up with a "universal" advantage or disadvantage either way off the top my head, but I would not be surprised if I was overlooking something.  Just be careful to not to be "too clever"... Note that is is *different* from `var Test = function () { return Test.stuff }` in a global-context because `Test` might really be `window.Test`, a property, and not a closed-over variable. Someone might break things later with `Test = function(){}` ... never know :)

Comment: I don't like to use `arguments.callee`. Neither do I like to use `var Test = function () { return Test.stuff; };`. Both are slow methods to access data. This is because `callee` is a method of `arguments`, and the interpreter spends more time accessing it. Similarly, `Test` does not exist within the local scope. Hence the interpreter must travel upwards to locate it in a parent scope. Instead, I prefer the following method: `var Test = function Temp() { return Temp.stuff; };`. Here `Temp` is an alias for `Test` and it exists within the local scope. It's a faster and a more elegant solution. ;)

Comment: @AaditMShah Shah Claims of "slow methods" rejected: *It Just Doesn't Matter*. List to Donald Knuth -- he *is* right about this topic. As far as "speed": a smart JavaScript engine can entirely eliminate scope traversal as it can be eliminated while preserving all the required semantics and, even with a dumb JavaScript engine, the *relative cost is insignificant* for most practical purposed. Willing to accept jsperf performance test-cases, bearing in mind they are micro-benchmarks.

Comment: @pst - [Speed Up Your Javascript - GoogleTechTalks - Nicholas C. Zakas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU "Speed Up Your JavaScript"). BTW what does Donald Knuth have to do with this?

Comment: @pst - Here you are assuming that the JavaScript engine is __smart__. What if the code is being executed on IE 6? Did you take that into consideration? All I'm trying to say is that this __my__ preferred method to tackle such a problem. In any case, it's still faster than the one you described; and if you put it in a really long loop then the difference does become significant. It's a best practice which makes sense to me. I already described why. It's upto you to accept it or not.

Comment: @AaditMShah Unfortunately your method appears flawed. Try this in both FF and IE: `var x = function y () { return y }; y = 42; x()`. In FF8 it evaluates to a function-object, in IE9 it evaluates to 42. I believe IE9 is "more correct", as I was unaware the name of the function was added to the local-scope of the function implicitly. There has historically been issues with function-declarations vs. function-expressions.

Comment: [As far as Knuth](http://scalibq.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/premature-design-is-the-root-of-all-evil/) -- I find the *end* of that quote excerpt better than the start.

Comment: @pst - IE9 evaluates it incorrectly. The identifier `y` must only exist within the local scope of the function. Thus the variable `x` should be an instance of `Function` and not `42`. The global and local variables `y` should be separate. In any case Mozilla's implementation is always "more correct" than IE9. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321 "Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax") for more details.

Comment: I read the article relating to Donald Knuth, and I agree that premature optimization in most cases is a waste of time. However, in this context it's not really the case of premature optimization. It's just about good coding practices. You don't really waste your time by using a certain pattern. You may use any pattern that suits you. I feel that this is a better pattern and hence I use it. It's a kind of ad-hoc optimization. One which comes as a side effect to your actual code. You're not really trying to squeeze the most performance, just following a good practice. Plus, it's simpler to read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4946/discussion-between-aadit-m-shah-and-pst)

Comment: @AaditMShah While the linked post does discuss the differences between function-declarations and function-expressions it does not discuss the behavior of the function *name* inside function body as an *identifier* for said function-expression. The example `var Test = function Temp() { return Temp.stuff; };` relies upon this behavior. As shown in the previous examples, assuming a top-level scope, IE is semantically the same as `var Test = function Temp () { return window.Temp(); }`, while FF is not. It would be interesting to see where, in the specification FF (or IE) is "correcter".

Comment: @AaditMShah Proving that IE is incorrect does not validate the aforementioned approach; only proving that FF is correct does. Additionally, for the approach "to be better" than the closure (or callee) samples requires that the function *name* is indeed bound as a *local variable* within said functions scope, per specification.

Comment: @pst - See the 10th page of this [PDF](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=resources:resources&cache=cache&media=resources:jscriptdeviationsfromes3.pdf) from ECMAScript - section 2.7 (Function Expressions). That should answer all your questions. It clearly shows that IE does not play well with the standards.

Comment: @pst - Every experienced web developer knows that any information which has its sources in IE is inadmissible in a court of law.

Comment: @AaditMShah No, section 2.7 does not explain why your code works or is valid. Your code asserts that in the case of `var Test = function Temp () { return Temp.bar }`, that `Temp` is an implicitly-created local-scoped variable (which is required to make the assertion that it doesn't use a *chained* [[scope]]; IE clearly uses a *chained* [[scope]], as demonstrated). Again. Proving IE "wrong" does not make FF "correct". As far as I can tell, they are *both* wrong and your approach is neither *valid per specification* nor *consistent across browsers*.

Comment: @AaditMShah To prove this alternative is "better" over closures would require **THE SPECIFICATION** to explicitly state that a function *name* is introduced into the [[scope]] of the function as a local *variable* bound to said function-object. Short of this the code is simply relying upon JS implementation quirks and, as demonstrated, may lead to "unexpected" behavior if `Temp` is changed outside the function.

Comment: Where is the "arguments.callee is deprecated" warning?

Comment: @Raynos I didn't know it was deprecated -- a link and I'll add it as appropriate :) Or ... feel free to edit away ^^

Comment: @pst - Click on [this link](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf "ECMA-262 Edition 5.1") to open the official ECMAScript specification. Search for `FunctionExpression : function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }`. It's on the 110th page of the PDF, page 98 of the official spec. Read the points 1 to 6. It's specified that in a named function expression's execution context's environment record there is an immutable binding called the String value of `Identifier` which is the function `closure` itself. The expression returns `closure`. =)

Comment: Wow it took me a lot of time to find that, but it was worth proving that IE is wrong. =D

Answer (score 5):

Class methods and variables go on the prototype property:

```
Test.prototype.stuff = 'Neat!'
```

Constructor functions (I'm assuming this is what you want, given the capital case and the `this`) should be invoked with the `new` operator:

```
new Test()
```

and they should not return a value (you should instead use the default that returns `this`)

```
function Test(){
    this.instanceVariable = 17;
    //no return!
}
```

---

As for your real need , you can just access the function and its properties directly then

```
function Test(){
    return Test.stuff;
}
```

However I am not a big fan of abusing functions for namespaces like that. I prefer to have a namespace object for doing things

```
//in a real case I would probably use the module pattern for private variables
//but whatever...

var Namespace = {};

Namespace.stuff = 'Neat!';

Namespace.F = function(){
    console.log(Namespace.stuff);
};
```

Comment: I actually want to use the class like the jQuery object (without instantiating): `Test('Do something'); Test.default = 500; Test('Do something with 500.')`

Comment: @AlicanC heres a post by John Resig on the topic. http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: @Pete that post is nice but it's from 2007. I can't find a single usage of `arguments.calee` in jQuery 1.7's source code now. Maybe they have moved to a new method? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @AlicanC - From what I understand, what you're really looking for is a pattern like the one I described in my answer (i.e. `var Test = function Temp() { return Temp.stuff; };`). It's fast, and it's elegant. Plus, even if people later change the code like `Test = 5;`, it will not break your code as the internal name of the function (i.e. `Temp`), still points to the function itself. It can't be modified from outside. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you have done:

```
var Test = function() {                //Test is a Function object
    return this.stuff;                 //this is a pointer to an object, not Test
};

Test.stuff = 'Neat!';                  //Add a property to Test

document.write(Test() || 'Not neat.'); //this has no property stuff
```

Change the last line of your code to:

```
document.write(Test.call(Test) || 'Not neat.'); //this now points to Test
```

The reason your code didn't work is because the `this` pointer points:

1. The instance of the constructor created when the function call is prefixed with the `new` keyword. (e.g. `var foo = new Foo(); //the this in Foo points to foo [for the sake of explanation]`).
2. The object passed to the `call` and `apply` functions as the first parameter.

What you want to do instead is something like:

```
var Test = function Temp() {           //Test is a Function object, alias Temp
    return Temp.stuff;                 //Temp is the same as Test, only locally
};

Test.stuff = 'Neat!';                  //Add a property to Test

document.write(Test() || 'Not neat.'); //writes Neat!
```

Upvote this answer if you liked it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You called `Test` from the global context, so `this` refers to the global object, so `this.stuff` refers to the global variable `stuff` which is `undefined` which is falsy.  This is why you saw `"Not neat."`

You can make it show `Neat!` like this:

See http://jsfiddle.net/aYh5y/

```
window.stuff = 'Neat!';
var Test = function() {
    return this.stuff;
};
alert(Test() || 'Not neat.');
```

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a way you can make `this` work as an *enclosing object*:

```
var Test = function () {
    return this.stuff;
};

var example = {
    g: Test,
    stuff: "Pretty neat"
};

alert(example.g() || 'Not neat.');
```

Here we're calling `Test` through a target object.

http://jsfiddle.net/aYh5y/1/

Answer (score 0):

The stuff property is assigned to the function, but read from the global this ... The two are seperate entities