# Javascript code not recognised in Intellij IDEA 12 in scala template for Play 2

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I just installed the recently released Intellij IDEA 12, which is GREAT for Play Framework 2.

However, I'm having the following issue: in an HTML Scala template, any JavaScript code enclosed in a `<script>` tag within the body of the template is not recognised as JavaScript by IDEA, thus not offering code completion and incorrectly showing errors where they aren't. I suspect it is interpreting the code as Scala code, ergo offering incorrect code completion and making it quite painful to write JS in a template.

This issue was not present in IDEA 11.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have the `JavaScript Support` plugin enabled. Simple code completion works fine. However, if I type `function (){}` to code an anonymous function and hit `Enter` with the caret between the curly brackets, IDEA does the following:

[image]

If I manually fix the incorrectly added `}`, and write code for the anonymous function, it offers correct variable suggestion for the `console.log` although it is stil showing errors:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I'm still seeing this behavior a year later in Play 2.2 with Idea 12 (ultimate).

Comment: No luck. Putting all my JavaScript in separate files :(

Answer (score 2):

I can't confirm that, I can see that both, Scala and JavaScript completion works properly.

Go to `Settings` > `Plugins` and make sure that you have `JavaScript Support` enabled. After that close and reopen all your views to let the Idea analize syntax once again.

[image]

Comment: I have the `JavaScript Support` plugin enabled, and your example works fine. However, try to code an anonymous function, or any code that has `{}` and unexpected errors will be marked. Check out the update to the question.

Comment: It seems that your anonymous function declaration is invalid :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1066240

Comment: I've tried all the possible ways of declaring an anonymous function stated on that question. However, the errors ("Missing }", "Wrong top statement declaration") persist. I strongly suspect it has to do with the curly brackets and most probably some configuration issue.

Comment: Actually, I copied some advanced JS from *.js file into template and indeed I can confirm problems with validation. Usually I'm trying to keep JS in own files, so maybe it will help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your function statement is invalid because you did not name your function. The details of what is going on here are answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax). I'm not sure of the details of your particular needs, but you might try this syntax instead:

```
<script>
    (function() {

    })();
</script>
```