# What is the name of this?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explain JavaScript’s encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

i don't understand completely what this does, so i wanted to look it up in google but I didn't find anything and realized that I don't know its name; so my question is: What is the name of this construction (?) :

```
( function ( ... ) {} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: that defines a function, which is then called with 3 parameters

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a [Self Executing Anonymous Function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/), or [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (IIFE), as [others also answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123589/1583).

Answer (score 3):

It's called a Self Executing Anonymous Function.

The purpose is to control scope so you aren't referencing globals or poluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

It's an [Self Executing Anonymous Function.](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/)

You can use these to prevent polluting or accessing the global (`window`) namespace with new `var`s.