# Values in parentheses after javascript function

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm trying to re-purpose some Javascript code I found linked in an answer on SO. But I would like to understand its syntax better first. Its outline is:

```
(function (root, ns, factory) {
    // some code
} (window, 'detectZoom', function() {
    // some more code
}));
```

See accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) for the reference to the full code.

I understand how the end-result is achieved, but I don't quite know how the inner (...) block relates to the first, or what the comma separated list inside it tells the compiler.

Can someone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an anonymous function taking  three parameters (`root`, `ns`, `factory`) which is immediately invoked.

- `root` takes the value of`window.
- `ns` takes the value of `'detectZoom'`
- `factory` takes the value of callback function (also anonymous)

The explanation:

```
(function (root, ns, factory) {
   // the body of the anonymous function
} (window, 'detectZoom', function() {
   // the body of the 'factory' callback
}));
```

To break it apart, how to get to this code in four steps:

```
 1.
 // Anonymous function.
 (function (root, ns, factory) {/* body */});

 2.
 // Anonynmous function, immediately invoked
 (function (root, ns, factory) {/* body */})();  // parentheses mean it's invoked

 3.
 // Callback as a separate argument
 var cbk = function () {};
 (function (root, ns, factory) {/* body */})(window, 'detectZoom', cbk);

 4.
 // Callback as an anonymous function
 (function (root, ns, factory) {/* body */})(window, 'detectZoom', function () {});
```

You could rewrite your code to be more verbose:

```
var outer = function (root, ns, factory) {
  // the body
};

var callback = function () {
  // the body
};

outer(window, 'detectZoom', callback);
```

Answer (score 11):

What you have is a immediately-invoked function expression ([IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)). If you strip out all the arguments you're just left with this:

```
(function () {
    // some code
}());
```

The function expects three arguments:

```
(function (root, ns, factory) {
    // some code
}());
```

And you pass it three arguments:

```
(function (root, ns, factory) {
    // some code
} (window, 'detectZoom', function() {
    // some more code
}));
```

One of those arguments, `factory`, happens to be a function.

Answer (score 1):

It creates an anonymous (unnamed) function that accepts three parameters:

```
function (root, ns, factory) {
    // some code
}
```

Then immediately calls that function passing three arguments, the third one being another anonymous function:

```
(window, 'detectZoom', function() {
    // some more code
})
```

The two blocks need to be wrapped inside a pair of `()`; the reason is explained here:
[Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)