# JavaScript anonymous function valid syntax preventing global scope polution?

Tags: javascript

I found such two code and not understand the difference between them if any exists.

Can you explain me what is difference between code preventing global scope polution.

First:

```
(function() {
var x = 1;
// thousand of lines here
}(window));
```

Second:

```
(function() {
var x = 1; 
// thousand of lines here
})(window);
```

Question can be trivial but I am not understand difference what is doing `();` - can you explain it?

Comment: If that's really exactly what the code looks like, then the difference is that the first one is not a syntax error, but the second one is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

Comment: I forget one to add some more () - check this now.

Comment: This is a duplicate (sometimes it can be hard to find them if you don't know the right terms to search for), and the other answer is really worth reading. He put a lot of good stuff in there.

Comment: It is not question how to do anonymous function or execute but why this syntax works?

Comment: @Chameleon look at CMS's answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax).

Comment: @minitech answer is honey - now I am understand what I am writing thousand times :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the JavaScript parser reads a `function` token at the start of the line, it assumes it’s a function declaration, i.e.

```
function hello() {
    return "world";
}
```

When it doesn’t see a name after that, it’s a syntax error. The parentheses make the context an expression instead of a statement/declaration, meaning that a function literal is expected.

Fun fact: you don’t need parentheses to force an expression context, of course. Unary operators will work too, e.g.

```
!function() {
    var x = 1;
}();
```

---

Oh, and you’ve gone and changed the question. The new answer is: they’re both exactly the same, kind of like `5 + (4 * 3)` versus `(5 + 4 * 3)`, except even less important because they’re more or less equally readable.

Comment: Now I am understand () is similar operator like ! both forces evaluation - thanks - this question irritate me long - it is so trivial :)