# what does new Function()() mean?

Tags: javascript, function, expression

I saw this code while working on a project and am not sure what it does exactly. Someone please educates me. Thanks.

```
var f = new Function('return '+terms)($element);
return f($element);
```

The new Function()() looks to me like an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression and if it is it would return the value from 'return '+terms' expression, correct? Then why is f being called as a function in the return statement?

**Updates:**

1. terms is an array containing just one element 'required', $element is a jQuery object of an HTML element
2. Code execution never gets past the `new Function()` statement with the error message Uncaught ReferenceError: required is not defined. So inside `new Function()()` the function required() is invoked.
3. I've never seen `new Function()()` syntax before. If it is an IIFE shouldn't it be written as `(new Function(){})()` instead?

Comment: In this case? It means whoever wrote it is a bad programmer.

Comment: `new Function` is similar to `eval`.  It returns a function and when ran will `eval` the string passed to it.  Apparently it returns another function, which is then called.

Comment: You may find an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax

Comment: Do you know what (the values of) `terms` and `$element` are?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I'd say they're variables. Yuk yuk!

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Happy now? :-)

Comment: That's the worst coding practice I've ever seen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that it's a invoked function - you can test it for yourself by doing:

```
var f = new Function("return 'a'")('b'); 
console.log(f);
```

`'a'`

The code you've posted can only work if `terms` is a string representing a function, meaning:

```
var f = new Function("return new Function('return arguments')")();
console.log(f, f(5));
```

`function anonymous() { return arguments } [5]`

Needless to say, it's rather peculiar way of writing JS.

Regarding the updates:

Actually what happens if terms = `['required']` is that this is transformed to a string by `'return '+terms`, so you have <strike>`new Function("return 'required'")`. As this is a function that returns `'required'` trying to invoke it as a function - `required($elem)` will give you indeed reference error.</strike> `new Function("return required")`. As this is a function that returns `required`, which isn't defined it will give you indeed reference error.

No, that's an acceptable way of writing it. More common is `(new Function("[function body]"))()` and in case of functions created without usage of Function object - `(function(){})()`. While `new Function("[function body]")()` will successfully run due to `new` operator precedence over `()` trying to run `function(){}()` will produce error.

Comment: Actually `'return '+terms` would wind up being `'return required'`.  So, the `eval` fails since it can't find the variable `required`.