# angularjs use strict in plunker

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I'm using plunker and I have a separate angular file app.js. I want to 'use strict' but I get 'angular' is not defined. Is there a way to avoid this error and keep app.js as a separate file? Here is my code app.js code

```
   'use strict';

   var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'World';
   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is highly recommended to put the `'use strict';` statement inside of a function - [source](http://jslinterrors.com/use-the-function-form-of-use-strict).

Just wrap all of your code in an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax) (which is the recommended way of doing it).

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
  });

})();
```

Sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ShbhkuN3MXTHzmdrL3c5?p=preview