# What is the difference between these function calls?

Tags: javascript

They both return the same result. But what is the difference?

```
(function (val) {
    console.log("val1: ", val);
}("FOO"));


(function (val) {
    console.log("val2: ", val);
})("FOO");


val1:  FOO
val2:  FOO
```

Comment: None. Why do you think there was any?

Comment: @Bergi, I usually use the second one. But yesterday I was implementing the Slick lib (a jQuery carousel) and they use the first version. So, I'm curious if there is a difference.

Comment: IMO the question *if* there is a difference between `(function(){})()` and `(function(){}())` and why `function(){}()` doesn't work is a valid question...

Comment: @Mathias: Yes - an [answered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)…