# for loop not working printing incorrect values. need index

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't understand why the for loop does not work properly

```
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { 
url= 'http://capc-pace.phac-aspc.gc.ca/details-eng.php?project='+x;
urllib.request(url, function (err, data, res) {
    if (err || res.statusCode !=200) {
    }
    else{
    console.log(x);
    }
});
}
```

I always get this as my response

```
s452:scripts 04101frt$ node javascriptparser.js 
10
10
10
10
10
```

I would expect to get all the pages that don't have redirect (i.e. their numbers in their url's)

The amount of numbers turn out fine (5 in this case) but I want to have their proper value.

Comment: @GregHewgill, why? that one asks for why immediately invoking a function declaration is a syntax error.

Comment: With all due respect, I must insist, that linked question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax) doesn't tell a thing about closures. That one is about syntax. This one is about semantics. And probably a dupe, but OP won't find any answer on that question.

Comment: This probably is the most suited duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work This indeed is a duplicate of many for sur, since this kind of question popup a lot daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into here is caused by javascript's function level scope. Take a moment and read this - it explains really well what is going on
http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Here's a fiddle to visualize the problem even more so -

http://jsfiddle.net/tm604oLu/

```
var url;
//wrong: because of being all on the same scope the value of x is 9 at the time it's evaluated
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    url = 'http://capc-pace.phac-aspc.gc.ca/details-eng.php?project=' + x;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(url);
    }, 1);
}

//correct behavior: by passing the url as the parameter to a function you are creating a new 'scope' and the value does not get overwritten
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    url = 'http://capc-pace.phac-aspc.gc.ca/details-eng.php?project=' + x;
    (function (ownScope) { 
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(ownScope);
        }, 1);
    }(url));
}
```

By creating an IFFE (immediately invoked function expression) you create a new scope - which helps preserve the intended value for your counter.

Comment: hoisting is generally a bad thing, but hoisting is innocent on this one.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are using closures, ain't you?

Closure is the thing that capture the variable `x` from parent scope inside  anonymous function. `x` will always refer to the last value assigned by that variable, even if the function that "created" the variable has long finished.

You need to pass a copy of the variable's value during each step. Something like this:

```
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { 
  url= 'http://capc-pace.phac-aspc.gc.ca/details-eng.php?project='+x;
  (function (x) {
    urllib.request(url, function (err, data, res) {
      if (err || res.statusCode !=200) {
      }
      else{
        console.log(x);
      }
    }
  })(x);
}
```

See what we have done? A new immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) receives a value for its argument. This way we effectively create 10 copies of the loop counter. `console.log(x)` refers to this parameter, not the outer loop counter.

Comment: You could just abstract out the request call to a function which takes argument x and just invoke the function with x in the loop :) I believe that would probably be more clean and readable. Which you can achieve with forEach  as well.