# javascript blank wrapper function

Tags: javascript

What purpose does the outer parentheses serve:

(function (){}());

As I understand it I am creating an anonymous function, then calling it with the (), but what does the outer parentheses do? I've seen this in a video tutorial, but it wasn't fully explained.

Comment: It's a dirty hack that helps JS parser to understand that it's a function expression not a function statement. And, yes, it's completely counter-intuitive.

Comment: I woudln't call it a "hack"; it's just JavaScripte syntax.

Comment: This should cover it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax

Comment: @Pointy it's a syntax approach caused by poor language design (that's what I usually call hack)

Answer (score 3):

> Those are the self-executing part. The first set of brackets contain the expressions to be executed, and the second set of brackets executes those expressions.

**And why are those () extras?**

you need to use them because when the Javascript Parser run and see the `function keyword`, so he will assume you are starting a a function statement and you will get some nasty `syntax error,`

also you need to know that function expressions and function statements are two differents things but unfortunately the syntax is almost equal, so thats why we are using those () extras, like @zerkms says its kinda a "hack"

Comment: The quote you've provided is completely irrelevant to the question

Comment: @zerkms i think the answer update its more clear now, isn't?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. It does not explain why you need the outer parentheses.

Comment: @zerkms its that update ok? or you think i should delete this answer?

Comment: Yep, now it looks fine, not sure why you was downvoted. +1

Answer (score 0):

Putting the outer parentheses  means You are going to execute it not to define, this is to do with the JS parsing rules. You always have the option to do this nicer than this lame way.  :)

Hope this helps!