# What does functionName(function() {...}) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the meaning of `addHorizonLoadEvent(function() {...})` in the following snippet?

```
addHorizonLoadEvent(function() {
    show_hide_datepickers();
});
```

Comment: It is an anonymous function

Comment: [addHorizonLoadEvent](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/65db6d33aa40a202cd16ad60e08273f715a67745/horizon/templates/horizon/client_side/_script_loader.html): _" Added so that we can append Horizon scoped JS events to the DOM load events without running in to the "horizon" name-space not currently being defined since we load the scripts at the bottom of the page."_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname?rq=1

Comment: @NeelabhSingh Could you accept an answer, please?

Answer (score 5):

`addHorizonLoadEvent` is a **higher-order function** -- that means it doesn't expect a non-function value (like a number, or a string) as it's argument, but *another function*. So the first argument is a new function, that will be called by the original function at some point (often at the end as a **callback**).

`function() {...}` is an **anonymous function** -- a way to express a function without *binding* it to a name.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you give a function as parameter of addHorizonLoadEvent.

You could do that :

```
var fooBar = function() {
   //alert("Alert2");
   show_hide_datepickers();
});

addHorizonLoadEvent(fooBar);
```

And the function parameter you give to addHorizonLoadEvent will be used only one time, no need to give it a name, so it is an **anonymous function**, directly declared in ().

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is a called anonymous function.

```
function_name(function() { 
    // Code
});
```

Is the same as writing

```
function my_function() {
    // Code
}
function_name(my_function);
```

Meaning that `my_function` is passed as an argument to the function `function_name`.

Comment: Is *similar to* .. but is *not* "the same". I've linked some relevant questions.