# Why is {}+[] different from ({}+[])?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

I was recently alarmed to discover the following:

```
> {}+[]
0

> ({}+[])
"[object Object]"

> {}+[]+1
1

> ({}+[])+1
'[object Object]1'

> {}+[] == ({}+[])
false
```

Why does wrapping something in parenthesis change its type?

Comment: Basically, you're doing weird things in a non-compiled language...so you're invoking strange defaults and behaviors that aren't defined in spec...

https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @CaffGeek This behavior is completely by spec.

Comment: where? (genuinely curious if that's in there)

Comment: Of course it's in there. It's just how tokens are regarded by lexical analysis and how they are casted as operands for `+`, nothing uncommon.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate but I can't find a good one.

Comment: And for the record `( )` do not change the type of anything. They alter the way the parser interprets tokens in certain ambiguous situations. (Actually it's more like, they alter the *situation* to change how tokens are interpreted.)

Comment: Wow, I would have never been able to find that earlier question with the search terms I was using (permutations on "javascript parenthesis type conversion" etc).  Also, this business of ({}+[])+1 != {}+[]+1 doesn't show up in the Wat talk.

Comment: Parentheses can also convert function declarations to function expressions: [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1529630)

Comment: @Crashworks for more laughs try `({}+[])+1 == {}+[]+1` in your browser console.

Comment: @Pointy   (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{} + []` is an empty block followed by a an array with a unary `+` operator, which is essentially, which is `+[]` which is 0,

`({} + [])` is a literal object plus a literal array, both get converted into strings, the string value of an object is `"[object Object]"` plus the string value of an empty array which is `""`, hence the result you see.