# Why Self-Executing Anonymous works?

Tags: javascript, function, self-executing-function

I know about Self-Executing Anonymous. And usually we create them as

```
(function(){ return 1;})()
```

the reason - parser feature which didn't run if we use

```
function(){ return 1}()
```

But today I found that next code works too ( check brackets order )

```
(function(){ return 1;}())
```

`function(){ return 1; }()` still give me SyntaxError, as it should

Please explain why? Thx for reference to get more details

P.S. the question is about `(function(){ return 1;}())` variant!

Comment: you didn't close the paraenthesis in ( function(){ return 1; }()

Comment: it's text which contains function -- there is all correct

Comment: Because that is not correct syntax. This: `function(){ return 1; }()` simply is not defined as valid syntax as it is.

Comment: @LunZhang You mean in the last line? The first parenthesis isn’t part of the code.

Comment: @Cristy The questions is why it WORKS, not 'why in NOT works'

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @Cristy 'Douglas Crockford's style' didn't know. Thx

Comment: It’s for the same reason `{a: 1, b: 2}[a]` doesn’t work. Here, `{`…`}` is a block, not an object. It’s because the `{` is interpreted as a statement, not an expression. `({a: 1, b: 2})[a]` or `({a: 1, b: 2}[a])` do work, because `(`…`)` forces the `{`…`}` to be interpreted as an expression (object). It’s exactly the same for functions, because there are function statements and function expressions. Why? Because that’s how JavaScript was designed.

Comment: If you understand why the first one works, then you'll understand why the second works. The second should be no more mysterious than the first.

Comment: ...and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1634321/1106925) to a different question gives a pretty detailed explanation of why either work and the last one doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function() {})()
```

and

```
(function() {}())
```

are equivalent.

To call second example you can include `+` operator before function

```
+function(){ return 1 }()
```

See [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: There are better operators to use than `+`. The reason is that the `+` is overloaded as a binary operator, and so if you accidentally forget a semicolon after the previous expression, it will try to add that previous expression to the function. It's basically the same problem that people have with using `()`. If you're going to use an alternate operator to force an expression, use a unary operator, like `!` for example.

Comment: @squint _"There are better operators to use than `+`"_ , _"If you're going to use an alternate operator to force an expression, use a unary operator, like `!` for example."_ Yes, though not for this particular case; `!function(){ return 1 }()` returns `false` instead of `1`

Comment: @squint Alternatively, `;null, function(){ return 1 }();`

Comment: If the return value is being captured, there's no need for any operator to make the function a valid expression. But yeah, anything to avoid unexpected evaluation of the operator is better. I've used `void` at times in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase `IIFE` is a better term for these functions .. Immediately Invoked Function Expressions.

As for why they are the same:  The outer parens `()` simply make an expression and the `()` together do the invocation.

```
(function(){ return 1;})()
is the same as:
(function(){ return 1;}())


(function(){ return 1;})()
becomes
(functionexpression)()
becomes
functionexpression()
```

and

```
(function(){ return 1;}())
becomes
(functionExpression())
becomes   
functionExpression()
```

for the same reason that

`(3)+2`  is the same as `((3)+2)`.

**EDIT**

```
function(){ return 1; }()
```

Does NOT work because a `function statement` is different from a `function expression`.  Function statements cannot be immediately invoked.