# Significance of defining custom methods to window object in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am working on a project in javascript and while going through design pattern concepts came across following point.
I have a sample code as below:

```
 window.customfun = (function(){}())
```

Here i have two questions:
1) Can we not simply define a global function as below:

```
customfun = (function(){}())
```

2) `(function(){}())` is an anonymous function with its own evaluation environment but i have learnt that to be implemented as : `(funtion(){})()`see the position of parentheses around couple of parentheses. I found that both are working so i wanted to know if there is any difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sure, you can define global functions
2. No, there is actually no difference.

Is there a difference: `(1+(1)) === (1) + (1)` ?

Comment: So this means function(){}() = (funtion(){})() = (function(){}()) ?

Comment: @flamelite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-the-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax

Comment: Got your point thanks man :)