# Enclosing parentheses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parentheses

Could I get an explanation of the follow code snippet?

```
(function()
{
    alert();
})();
```

This looks like an anonymous function and the alert() function gets executed. I don't understand the semantic meaning of the outer parentheses. What does this part of the snippet mean?

```
(


 )()
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/3001761

Comment: I think the question is saying "Why not `function() {alert(1);}();`, but `+function() {alert(1);}();` or `(function() {alert(1);})();`?". However the answer is already on _Stack Overflow_.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this represents the immediately executable function. in easier way, it means that function being declared and called/executed simultaneously.