# Why does this throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to extend the functionality of a Promise and stumbled across this behaviour. I may be doing something silly but I'm confused.

Why does this code throw a SyntaxError?

```
Promise.constructor.call(this, function(){})
// Throws
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
//   at Function (<anonymous>)
//   at <anonymous>:1:21
```

However this is fine

```
Promise.constructor.call(this, () => {})
```

Comment: Note that `Promise.constructor.call(this, function foo(){})` is okay

Comment: Indeed, the mozilla version of this error points this out: `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in order to make this clear, notice that `Promse.constructor` is just a reference to the `Function` constructor.

So basically you are just calling:

```
Function.call(this, function () {})
```

and:

```
Function.call(this, () => {})
```

The first expression throws because `function () {}` is not a valid **function statement** (but it's a valid function *expression*).

The problem is that being at the top block of the scope, the `function` identifier is matching the grammar of the statement form of the function declaration, and function statements should be named (that's why the error says *`(` is an "unexpected token"*, the parser it's expecting a name between the `function` keyword and the `(` character).

If you do use a name, or use the comma operator, it will treat the function as an expression:

```js
console.log(Function('0,function () {}'))

console.log(Function('function test() {}'))
```

With arrow functions there is no problem since they can only be expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Learnt something new.

Comment: @Ally, you're welcome, if you want to go deeper in the differences between function statements vs expressions check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-the-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321 and https://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Answer (score 0):

You cant create anonymous function like this either way, it's not promise constructor problem;

```
function(){}
```

> Thrown: function(){}
>           ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (